# How do I create a matrix of functions?

Tags: functions, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix in which the elements are functions of two variables, but I can't figure out how to do it. Is it possible? The only way I could figure out is to define the matrix in terms of two variables, then replace those variables with values later on. Here's my code:

```
row1 = {};
row2 = {};
For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[modes], ii++,
  {l, m} = modes[[ii]];
  G1lm = sglm[-2, l, m, \[Theta]] + (-1)^l sglm[-2, l, -m, \[Theta]];
  G2lm = sglm[-2, l, m, \[Theta]] - (-1)^l sglm[-2, l, -m, \[Theta]];
  AppendTo[row1, G1lm Cos[m \[Phi]]];
  AppendTo[row1, G1lm Sin[m \[Phi]]];
  AppendTo[row2, G2lm Sin[m \[Phi]]];
  AppendTo[row2, -G2lm Cos[m \[Phi]]];
  ];
proj = {row1, row2};
```

Theta and Phi are my variables. Later on, when I want proj for a specific Theta and Phi I use replace:

```
pN = proj /. {\[Theta] -> a, \[Phi] -> b};
```

where a and b are some numbers. The problem with this solution is that if I use Theta and Phi for something else later on, say I set Theta = 0.5, then proj will permanently have Theta = 0.5, regardless of the replace I use. This happened to me: I was calling proj in a loop, but I kept getting the same results. After ripping my hair out for a few hours, I realized I had Theta set to a specific value in a block of code further up in my notebook. The simple solution is to simply not use Theta and Phi anywhere else in the notebook, but that doesn't seem very stable.

The root problem here is I'm using global variables to do something that should really be local to proj, but I don't know how to fix that. The ideal would be if I could somehow make proj a function of Theta and Phi so that later on I can simply do `pN = proj[a,b]`. I know how to make the Gnlm's functions of theta, but then I don't know how to make row1, row2, and by extension proj, functions of Theta (and Phi). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are `modes` and `sglm`? Otherwise I can only post a general answer on how to create a list of functions. Or rather, as it seems that is what you need, a function in two variables that creates a list.

Comment: `modes` is a 2x5 array of numbers --- specifically `{{2,2},{2,1},{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}}` --- and the `sglm` are the theta-dependent parts of the [spin-weighted spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-weighted_spherical_harmonics). Honestly, the exact functional form of the sglm doesn't matter --- you could just use Sin[l theta] and Cos[l theta] if you wish. The point is each element of the matrix is a different function of the same two variables, theta and phi.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need something like this:

```
proj[modes_][θ_, ϕ_] :=
 Table[
  MapThread[
   (sglm[-2, #1, #2, θ] + 
       sign (-1)^#2 sglm[-2, #1, -#2, θ]) 
     If[sign == -1, {Cos[#2 ϕ], 
      Sin[#2 ϕ]}, {Sin[#2 ϕ], -Cos[#2 ϕ]}]&,
   Transpose@modes],
  {sign, {-1, 1}}
  ]
```

The list of modes is iterated through automatically, without the use of `For`, by applying `MapThread` to `Transpose@modes`.

The two lists you combine in `proj` differ only in the value of the variable `sign` which is implemented inside `Table` that goes through the values `1` and `-1`.

The function takes `modes` as its initial argument, and the angles are the other two arguments. You don't need to separate them like I did, that's just a matter of taste. The main thing here is how you use the underscore to declare the function variables. And the function itself, called `proj`, then returns the list.

In conclusion: functions can return lists, and `For` loops can be replaced by `Map`, `MapThread` or `Table` (etc.).

**Edit**

If you want to really pre-compute everything as far as possible given a fixed list `modes`, you can do the following:

```
Clear[proj, θ, ϕ]
modes = {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}};   

proj[θ_, ϕ_] = 
 Table[Flatten[
   MapThread[(sglm[-2, #1, #2, θ] + 
        sign (-1)^#1 sglm[-2, #1, -#2, θ]) If[
       sign == 1, {Cos[#2 ϕ], 
        Sin[#2 ϕ]}, {Sin[#2 ϕ], -Cos[#2 ϕ]}] &, 
    Transpose@modes]], {sign, {1, -1}}]
```

`(* 
==> {{0,0,Cos[ϕ] (-sglm[-2,1,-1,θ]+sglm[-2,1,1,θ]),(-sglm[-2,1,-1,θ]+sglm[-2,1,1,θ]) Sin[ϕ],Cos[2 ϕ] (sglm[-2,2,-2,θ]+sglm[-2,2,2,θ]),(sglm[-2,2,-2,θ]+sglm[-2,2,2,θ]) Sin[2 ϕ]},{0,-2 sglm[-2,1,0,θ],(sglm[-2,1,-1,θ]+sglm[-2,1,1,θ]) Sin[ϕ],-Cos[ϕ] (sglm[-2,1,-1,θ]+sglm[-2,1,1,θ]),(-sglm[-2,2,-2,θ]+sglm[-2,2,2,θ]) Sin[2 ϕ],-Cos[2 ϕ] (-sglm[-2,2,-2,θ]+sglm[-2,2,2,θ])}}
 *)`

This uses `Set` instead of `SetDelayed` to evaluate the `modes` and (if possible) `sglm` at the time you define the function `proj`. Then the `MapThread` won't have to be repeated when you call the function. It won't save significant time to do this unless parts of the `sglm` can in fact be evaluated for symbolic arguments.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the trick. It looks like this is building the table on the fly each time. Do you know if there is much computational cost in that? I'm wondering if it is any faster to pre-construct proj for the given modes, ala `proj[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_]:= proj[modes][\[Theta],\[Phi]]`. I ask because `proj` is going inside FindMaximum. In that the number of modes always stays the same, just the angles change.

Comment: Since the variables $\theta$ and $\phi$ are inside the `sglmn`, you would indeed have to re-do the sum for every new $\theta$ and $\phi$. That's why I don't see any significant room for improvement in terms of efficiency. But certainly you can leave out the `modes` argument if that stays fixed as a global variable. Then you don't even need to include it in my definition above, just make sure `modes` is defined once you call the function.

Comment: As far as I see it, that would still mean the whole `MapThread` procedure is done every time the function is called. I think the OP wants to precompute everything, to get a function that really only inserts the arguments into the precomputed list.

Comment: @einbandi But that essentially costs nothing.

Comment: Good point. I think it's interesting nevertheless, how one can compute complicated things and turn them to a function _afterwards_. Is there a standard way of replacing certain variables in an expression by `Slot`s in order to create a function?

Comment: @einbandi OK, I've added an approach that does this to the answer.

Comment: I was rather thinking of a way that really returns a `Function` object. Now that I'm interested in it, I might actually write up a seperate question.

Comment: @ccap83 I just noticed I didn't include the two cases for the sine versus cosine factors in your list. I added that with an `If` statement. It doesn't affect the logic of the answer, only the list becomes twice as long.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the update. This gives the correct elements, but there's a slight problem: the dimension of the output table is 2xNx2 where N is the number of modes. The dimension should be 2x2N. This is important because in my use proj is an operator that acts on another 2Nx2N matrix. Any suggestions on how to get the dimension to work out?

Comment: @Jens Btw, I'm finding that your method is about twice as fast as the replacement method I was originally using, so it is more computationally efficient. Now if I could only get the dimension to work out...

Comment: Sorry I didn't get around to fixing this earlier. I fixed the dimensions (also I had gotten your $\theta$ and $\phi$ the wrong way around in some places earlier).

Answer (score 1):

To build the table only when given (θ, ϕ) parameters I might use:

```
f1[θ_, ϕ_][{l_, m_}] := 
  With[{
     A = sglm[-2, l,  m, θ],
     B = sglm[-2, l, -m, θ],
     s = Sin[m ϕ],
     c = Cos[m ϕ]
    },
    {{c, s}, {s, -c}} (A + (-1)^l {1, -1} B)
  ]

f2[θ_, ϕ_, modes : {{_,_} ..}] := Flatten[f1[θ, ϕ] /@ modes, {{2}, {1, 3}}]
```

Then for example:

```
f2[2.5, 7.2, {{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}}]
```

In this construct all symbols are localized except for the function `sglm` and `f1` and `f2` themselves.
I could have put `f1` in a `Module` inside `f2` but I felt this presentation was cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I'm finding it to be about 6x's slower than the replacement method I was using originally: `Mean[Table[Timing[f2[0.5 Pi, 0.25 Pi, modes]][[1]], {i, 1, 1000}]]` gives ~6e-4s, `Mean[Table[
  Timing[proj /. {\[Theta] -> 0.5 Pi, \[Phi] -> 0.25 Pi}][[1]], {i, 1,
    1000}]]` gives ~1e-4s.

Comment: @ccap83 You did not seem to stress performance so I did not focus on that.  If you provide the definition of your `sglm` function I can probably make my code faster, and perhaps yours too.

Answer (score 0):

Using the question posted by @einbandi and answer posted by @acl [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/how-can-i-turn-an-expression-to-a-function-inside-a-module) the general solution seems to be:

```
Module[{vars},
   mat = {(*Some code that constructs a matrix out of expressions of vars*)}
   fmat = Function @@{{vars}, mat};
]
```

Applying to my specific case, the following works:

```
Module[{\[Theta], \[Phi]},
 row1 = {};
 row2 = {};
 For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[modes], ii++,
  {l, m} = modes[[ii]];
  G1lm = sglm[-2, l, m, \[Theta]] + (-1)^l sglm[-2, l, -m, \[Theta]];
  G2lm = sglm[-2, l, m, \[Theta]] - (-1)^l sglm[-2, l, -m, \[Theta]];
  AppendTo[row1, G1lm Cos[m \[Phi]]];
  AppendTo[row1, G1lm Sin[m \[Phi]]];
  AppendTo[row2, G2lm Sin[m \[Phi]]];
  AppendTo[row2, -G2lm Cos[m \[Phi]]];
  ];
 proj = Function @@ {{\[Theta], \[Phi]}, {row1, row2}};
 ]
```

Enclosing the construction of the matrix in a Module ensures that `\[Theta]` and `\[Phi]` are protected, and the last line turns `proj` into a function of the two variables. This method is also fast: it's about twice as fast as the replacement method I was originally using.

I'm sure there's much more concise ways to construct the matrix than the For loop I'm using here, but since this part of the code is only called once, any computational time savings are negligible.