# Unexpected variable renaming depending on form of a pure function

Tags: replacement, core-language, scoping, pure-function, language-design

I encountered unexpected difference in variable renaming behavior depending on whether a pure function with a named parameter, or a pure function with a slot is used:

```
{x_, y_, z_} :> # & /@ {{y, z, x}, {z, x, y}}
(* {{x_, y_, z_} :> {y, z, x}, {x_, y_, z_} :> {z, x, y}} *)

Function[s, {x_, y_, z_} :> s] /@ {{y, z, x}, {z, x, y}}
(* {{x$_, y$_, z$_} :> {y, z, x}, {x$_, y$_, z$_} :> {z, x, y}} *)
```

Is there an explanation for this?

---

*Update:* It was suggested that this question is a duplicate of another, already answered question. I read that question and answers, but still do not understand why is it significant whether the function parameter is named or unnamed? There is nothing in conflict with its name `s`. The conflict happens for the names `x`, `y`, `z`, and it happens regardless whether we use a named or unnamed parameter. So this question is still open for me.

Comment: Why is that unexpected? [Variables in Pure Functions and Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html)

Comment: @Karsten7. Ok, I can see why renaming happens in the second case, but why there is difference between 2 forms of a pure function?

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `Function[{x_, y_, z_} :> #] /@ {{y, z, x}, {z, x, y}}`, which is like using `Function[Null, {x_, y_, z_} :> #] /@ {{y, z, x}, {z, x, y}}`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not see how it explains a different behavior.

Comment: You need to read the documentation article [Variables In Pure Functions And Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html)

Comment: The second one has an enclosing localization (similar to `With[{s = #}, {x_, y_, z_} :> s] & /@ {{y, z, x}, {z, x, y}}`) and the first one doesn't.

Comment: The second pure function has a named formal parameter (`s`) localized to that pure function and the first pure function has an unnamed formal parameter (`#`, and therefore no localization).

Comment: @Karsten7. This difference is not considered in the referenced Documentation article, so the question is perfectly legitimate and deserves a good answer.

Comment: Related: [(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121)

Comment: Why is it significant whether the function parameter is named or unnamed? There is nothing in conflict with its name `s`. The conflict happens for the names `x`, `y`, `z`, and it happens regardless whether we use a named or unnamed parameter. I could not find an explanation or justification for this behavior neither in the referenced question, not in the referenced documentation page, so this question is still open for me.

Comment: "The conflict happens for the names `x`, `y`, `z`, ..." Nope, compare `Function[s, {x_, y_, z_} :> s] /@ {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}`. It's about `RuleDelayed` being inside a scoping construct (`Function[{x,…},body]`) or a non-scoping one (`Function[body]`).

Comment: @Vladimir I cannot see where anyone suggested that this question is a duplicate.  Certainly I did not.  My "Related:" links are primarily for site organization.  It is a lovely day and I am going outside, but if I remember I'll answer this later.

Comment: Also related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25437/4999 -- The approach in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34350/4999 also works here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that it is better to start with the second part of the question, and only then move on to the first part.

> There is nothing in conflict with its name `s`. The conflict happens for
>   the names `x`, `y`, `z`, and it happens regardless whether we use a named or
>   unnamed parameter. So this question is still open for me.

Actually there is no scoping conflict which involves names `x`, `y`, `z`. We can simplify your example and get the same behavior:

```
Function[s, {x_, y_, z_} :> s]@d
```

> ```
> {x$_, y$_, z$_} :> d
> ```

As you see, variables are renamed despite the fact that they aren't used anywhere except to `RuleDelayed` inside of `Function`. So there is no conflict but rather this is [how nested *lexical* scoping implemented in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/280). We can replace `RuleDelayed` with `Function` in order to emphasize this point:

```
Function[s, Function[{x, y, z}, s]]@d
```

> ```
> Function[{x$, y$, z$}, d]
> ```

... or replace `Function` with `RuleDelayed`:

```
d /. RuleDelayed[s_, RuleDelayed[{x_, y_, z_}, s]]
```

> ```
> {x$_, y$_, z$_} :> d
> ```

... or we can try the same construct with `With`:

```
With[{s = d}, With[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> `With::lvws`: Variable `x$` in local variable specification `{x$,y$,z$}` requires a value. >>
>
> ```
> With[{x$, y$, z$}, d]
> ```

Here the inner `With` isn't evaluated because of incorrect semantics but the variables are already renamed by the outer `With`! Again, there is no scoping conflict.

It is worth to stress that the outer lexical scoping construct renames the parameters of the inner *before* the latter is evaluated in any sense. We can make the inner construct completely inert by wrapping it with `HoldComplete` in order to emphasize this point:

```
With[{s = d}, HoldComplete@With[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[With[{x$, y$, z$}, d]]
> ```

```
Module[{s}, HoldComplete@Module[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[Module[{x$, y$, z$}, s$603]]
> ```

For non-lexical scoping constructs the renaming of variables isn't performed:

```
With[{s = d}, HoldComplete@Block[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[Block[{x, y, z}, d]]
> ```

```
With[{s = d}, HoldComplete@Internal`InheritedBlock[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> HoldComplete[Internal`InheritedBlock[{x, y, z}, d]]
> ```

... and non-lexical scoping constructs themselves do not rename variables in inner scoping constructs (regardless whether the latter are *lexical* or not):

```
Block[{s = d}, Rule[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> {x, y, z} -> d
> ```

```
Block[{s = d}, Hold@Module[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Module[{x, y, z}, s]]
> ```

```
Block[{s = d}, Hold@Block[{x, y, z}, s]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Block[{x, y, z}, s]]
> ```

The *necessary* condition for renaming of variables of the inner scoping construct is that its body is modified by the outer scoping construct. For example, in the following examples lexical replacement doesn't change the body, and that's why no renaming is performed:

```
Function[x, Function[y, x]][x]
```

> ```
> Function[y, x]
> ```

```
With[{x = x}, Function[{y, z}, x]]
```

> ```
> Function[{y, z}, x]
> ```

Excepting `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` (see below), the outer scoping constructs respect the inner *lexical* scope:

```
Function[x, Function[x, x]][y]
```

> ```
> Function[x, x]
> ```

```
Function[{x, y}, Function[x, x + y]][a, b]
```

> ```
> Function[x$, x$ + b]
> ```

```
With[{x = a, y = b}, Function[x, x + y]]
```

> ```
> Function[x$, x$ + b]
> ```

The only exceptions are `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` which in the situations of direct conflict with enclosed scoping construct break the scope of the latter and perform lexical replacement without renaming of *conflicting* variables:

```
(* body isn't modified *)

y /. RuleDelayed[x_, Function[{x, z}, y + z]]
```

> ```
> Function[{y, z}, y + z]
> ```

```
(* body is modified *)

y /. RuleDelayed[x_, Function[{x, z}, x + y + z]]
```

> ```
> Function[{y, z$}, y + y + z$]
> ```

```
y /. RuleDelayed[x_, RuleDelayed[{x_, z_}, x + y + z]]
```

> `RuleDelayed::rhs`: Pattern `x_` appears on the right-hand side of rule `x_:>{x_,z_}:>x+y+z`.
>
> ```
> {y_, z$_} :> y + y + z$
> ```

```
y /. RuleDelayed[x_, Hold@Module[{x, z}, x + y + z]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Module[{y, z$}, y + y + z$]]
> ```

```
(* modified body of non-lexical scoping construct *)

y /. RuleDelayed[x_, Hold@Block[{x, z}, x + y + z]]
```

> ```
> Hold[Block[{y, z}, y + y + z]]
> ```

Now we can move to the first part of the question: why completely anonymous pure functions (the form `Function[body]` or `body &`) do not rename variables in inner scoping constructs?

The answer is that they ... just implemented this way :). Outer scoping constructs can't rename unnamed parameters of completely anonymous pure functions, and anonymous pure functions themselves do not rename variables in other scoping constructs. In this respect they are unique in the Wolfram Language and exactly this feature allows transparent building of new scoping constructs at the run-time:

```
expr = x^2;
(y[x_, z_] := #) &@expr;
Definition[y]
```

> ```
> y[x_, z_] := x^2
> ```

```
RuleDelayed[{x_, z_}, ## + y + z] &[x, y]
```

> ```
> {x_, z_} :> x + y + y + z
> ```

---

### What can we find in the Documentation on the subject?

The above case with nested `Function`s is [covered](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html) in the Documentation explicitly:

> Here is a nested pure function.
>
> ```
> Function[{x}, Function[{y}, x + y]]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Function[{x}, Function[{y}, x + y]]
> > ```
>
> The Wolfram Language renames the formal parameter `y` in the inner
>   function to avoid conflict with the global object `y`.
>
> ```
> %[2 y]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > Function[{y$}, 2 y + y$]
> > ```
>
> The resulting pure function behaves as it should.
>
> ```
> %[a]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > a + 2 y
> > ```

And at the next line (emphasis is mine):

> **In general, the Wolfram Language renames the formal parameters in an object *like* `Function[vars,body]` whenever `body` is modified in any
>   way by the action of another pure function.**

I wish to stress the word ***like***: from the examples in the previous section it should be clear that *lexical* scoping constructs `Function`, `RuleDelayed`, `With` work very similarly and are interchangeable. So the Documentation clearly states that the same rule is applied to any of these constructs in a situation of nested scoping.

I recommend to read the referenced Documentation page carefully up to the end. Here I'll emphasize a paragraph that should ultimately answer your question (emphasis is mine):

> The Wolfram Language renames formal parameters in pure functions
>   more liberally than is strictly necessary. In principle, **renaming could be avoided** if the names of the formal parameters in a particular function **do not actually conflict** with parts of
>   expressions substituted into the body of the pure function. For
>   uniformity, however, the Wolfram Language still renames formal
>   parameters even in such cases.

**P.S.** I must stress that every mentioning of *pure function* in this section (and also on the [linked](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html) Documentation page) should be read as *pure function with named arguments* and shouldn't be applied to *anonymous* pure functions (without named arguments). The latter are very special in the WL: they do not interfere with symbols (or named parameters) in any way. For example they change the `body` of `Function` without renaming its parameters what allows to break scoping, compare:

```
Function[{y}, #] &[y]
```

> ```
> Function[{y}, y]
> ```

```
Function[{x}, Function[{y}, x]][y]
```

> ```
> Function[{y$}, y]
> ```

Comment: Thanks. What are the grounds for your claim that `Function[body]` is non-scoped? Is it explicitly mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: I have spent some time searching in the Documentation but haven't found an explicit statement. But it is mentioned in the book by @LeonidShifrin. I updated the answer with this information and added some rationalization.

Comment: @Vladimir Finally I removed that statement from the answer. As a result of more detailed acquaintance with definition of the term "[scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))" and experimenting I come to the conclusion that `Function[body]` is indeed a lexical scoping construct. And @LeonidShifrin [agreed](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124583/is-anonymous-pure-function-a-scoping-construct/124588?noredirect=1#comment337424_124588) with me that `Function[body]` is a scoping construct (just very limited in its capabilities as compared to others).

Answer (score 5):

Adapting Rojo's approach in [Using With to scope over pure functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34345/using-with-to-scope-over-pure-functions/34350#34350):

```
Function[s, Identity[RuleDelayed][{x_, y_, z_}, s]] /@ {{y, z, x}, {z, x, y}}
(*  {{x_, y_, z_} :> {y, z, x}, {x_, y_, z_} :> {z, x, y}}  *)
```

Comment: All is more clear on the minimal example `Function[s, RuleDelayed[Pattern[x, y], s]]@1`.  Yes it is an idiosyncrasy of `RuleDelayed`.