# Problem with `Derivative`/`Series` and `InverseFunction`

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Here is the Mathematica code I'm asking about:

```
fn = InverseFunction[ Log@#+Exp@#& ];
Print[  fn'                 [1.]]
Print[  D[fn[x],x]      /.x->1. ]
Print[  D[fn[x],{x,2}]  /.x->1. ]
Print[  fn''                [1.]]
Print[  D[D[fn[x],x],x] /.x->1. ]
Print[ Normal @ Series[fn@x, {x, 1., 1}] ]
Print[ Normal @ Series[fn@x, {x, 1., 2}] ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z8tT8FWwTOvLLWoONWtNC@5JDM/L1rBJz/dQVnbtaLAQVlNIdaaK6AoM68kWkEhLU9dAR1EG@rFxsJVuESn5UVXxOpUxEJk9fUqdO0M9RQwVVRX6BjVxmJTAbRFnZAtCHtAVmGY4ZdflJuYo@CgEJxalJlaDFTsUKGjALRSwVAPiIH2EqnUCKz0/38A)

As you can see:

`fn` is a function defined using `InverseFunction`. We can assume that this function has no closed-form.

It has first-order and second-order numerical derivative at the point `1`, being `0.27614597273176456` and `0.04511431748742336` respectively.

However, calculate double derivative using `Derivative` (`fn''[1.]`) or `Series` (degree $\geq 2$) does not behave as expected, resolves to `InverseFunction'` object.

So, what's the best way to get the `Series` of that (and other similar) function?

Comment: Answers about the bug in particular (and whether is that a bug) is also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InverseFunction` and `Derivative[1]` operate on functions. So, supply them with functions:

```
h=.
f = InverseFunction[h];
f'[x]
```

> Derivative[1][h][InverseFunction[h][x]]^(-1)

In your case, this leads to:

```
h = x \[Function] Log[x] + Exp[x];
f'[x]
```

> 1/(E^InverseFunction[Function[x, Log[x] + Exp[x]]][x] + 1/ 
>   InverseFunction[Function[x, Log[x] + Exp[x]]][x])

Now also `Series` works. I use machine precision numbers in order to make the output readible:

```
Series[f[x], {x, 1., 4}] // TeXForm
```

> $$0.512222+0.276146 (x-1.)+0.0225572 (x-1.)^2-0.0123554
>    (x-1.)^3-0.0000787926 (x-1.)^4+O\left((x-1.)^5\right)$$

Comment: In conclusion: Anonymous function (`#&`) doesn't work, while explicit function (`Function[y,y]`) does work. Why? Is that a bug? They are both functions.

Comment: Also the wrap around `InverseFunction` is unnecessary - just `InverseFunction[...]` instead of `Function[x, InverseFunction[...][x]]` works, `InverseFunction` is supposed to return a function.

Comment: I have cleaned it up a bit. To my own surprise, lambda calculus seems not work. As a mathematician,  I prefer `Function` anyway. It was actually the one thing that convinced me to use Mathematica...

Comment: If I were you, I would file that as a bug to Wolfram support. My impression used to be that lambda calculus and `Function` are supposed to be equivalent...

Comment: Actually, lambda and `Function` are not exactly equivalent, as lambda can receive any number of argument while `Function` can only accept a fixed number of argument. However [this](https://tio.run/##jc3BCsIwDIDhu08RENzBWtmuovSggiAieCw5lNFpwWXSVekQn71WhQlO0EKgkJ98pXIHXSpnchVCQTCFFV20rfXyTLkzFUlofw2DdbUX/eHCn0R/IBtEwElvaw05CVBQAp9PphyxLeayIOmReXxtx9yPZimHbnH1LLvhtyIqyS/l7Tyozo1NZUt1BAE7bY2uYyw8g0hCyuNE9880e6Yh3AE "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") also doesn't work.

Comment: `Functions` also can receive more arguments than in its declaration. The remaining arguments are just ignored. Note that `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so you often have to apply `Evaluate` to its second argument, i.e., your example works with `fn = InverseFunction[Function[y, Evaluate[Log[#] + Exp[#] &[y]]]];`

Comment: Moreover, I'd like to say that it would be more transparent for others if you would simply copy small code snippets directly into StackExchange...

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using an anonymous pure function inside of [`InverseFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFunction) is that you get nested anonymous pure functions when evaluating the second derivative. Compare the following 2 [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint) outputs:

```
TracePrint[InverseFunction[Function[x, Log[x]+Exp[x]]]'', Derivative[1][_]];
TracePrint[InverseFunction[Log[#]+Exp[#]&]'', Derivative[1][_]];
```

> ((1/(Function[x,Log[x]+Exp[x]]^[Prime])[InverseFunction[Function[x,Log[x]+Exp[x]]][#1]]&)^[Prime])
>
> ((1/((Log[#1]+Exp[#1]&)^[Prime])[InverseFunction[Log[#1]+Exp[#1]&][#1]]&)^[Prime])

Notice how the the first trace output has a mixture of `x` and `#1`, while the second trace output replaces `x` with `#1`. The latter trace is an example of a nested pure function using anonymous pure functions, which is why it doesn't work. The issue of nested anonymous pure functions has come up before, see:

1. [Is anonymous pure function a scoping construct?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124583/45431)
2. [Pure function inside another pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38393/45431)

**Addendum**

You also ask:

> So, what's the best way to get the `Series` of that (and other similar) function?

Instead of taking the series of the inverse function, you can apply [`InverseSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseSeries) to the series expansion of the function. For example:

```
InverseSeries @ Series[Log[x]+Exp[x], {x, 1, 2}] //TeXForm
```

> $1+\frac{x-e}{1+e}-\frac{(e-1) (x-e)^2}{2 (1+e)^3}+O\left((x-e)^3\right)$

```
Series[
    InverseFunction[Function[x, Log[x]+Exp[x]]][x],
    {x, E, 2}
] //TeXForm
```

> $1+\frac{x-e}{1+e}+\frac{(1-e) (x-e)^2}{2 (1+e)^3}+O\left((x-e)^3\right)$

For clarity, I used an expansion point of 1 for the function, which corresponds to an expansion point of `E` for the inverse function. To get the expansion of the inverse function around 1 you could do:

```
pt = x /. First @ Solve[Log[x] + Exp[x]==1 && 0<x<1, x];
Simplify[
    InverseSeries @ Series[Log[x] + Exp[x], {x, a, 1}],
    Exp[a]+Log[a]==1
] /. a->pt //TeXForm
```

> $\operatorname{Root}\left[\left\{e^{\#1}+\log
>    (\#1)-1\&,0.51222243303322994816075176697026116734`20.304437036448245\right\}\right]+\frac{x-1}{e^{\operatorname{Root}\left[\left\{e^{\#1}+\log
>    (\#1)-1\&,0.51222243303322994816075176697026116734`20.304437036448245\right\}\right]}+\frac{1}{\operatorname{Root}\left[\left\{e
>    ^{\#1}+\log (\#1)-1\&,0.51222243303322994816075176697026116734`20.304437036448245\right\}\right]}}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$

which yields the same result:

```
Series[
    InverseFunction[Function[x, Log[x]+Exp[x]]][x],
    {x, 1, 1}
] //TeXForm
```

> $\operatorname{Root}\left[\left\{e^{\#1}+\log
>    (\#1)-1\&,0.5122224330332299481607867201842576827690521506497275993993`30.\right\}\right]+\frac{x-1}{e^{\operatorname{Root}\left
>    [\left\{e^{\#1}+\log
>    (\#1)-1\&,0.5122224330332299481607867201842576827690521506497275993993`30.\right\}\right]}+\frac{1}{\operatorname{Root}\left[\left\{e^{\#1}+\log
>    (\#1)-1\&,0.5122224330332299481607867201842576827690521506497275993993`30.\right\}\right]}}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$

Comment: Thanks! - So it's Mathematica implementation (use pure function to represent derivatives) that makes this impossible?

Comment: Isn't this a bug with handling pure functions by `Derivative`?