# Antiderivative of a piecewise function evaluates wrong inside a subroutine

Tags: function-construction, scoping

It's very helpfull to use antiderivative of a given function in the form `Derivative[-1][fun][t]`!

Here my example with a simple piecewise function:

```
fun = Which[0 <= t <= 1, Min[1, 2 (# (1 - #))/(1/2)^2], True, 0] &
Plot[fun[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The antiderivative evaluates as expected

```
Plot[(Derivative[-1][Function[t, fun[t]]][t]), {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

But if I try calculate the antiderivative inside a subroutine I get strange results:

```
test =.
test[fu_] :=Plot[(-Derivative[-1][Function[t, fu]][t]), {t, 0, 1},
                 Evaluated -> True] 
test[fun[t]]
```

[image]

My question:
What might be the reason for the obviously wrong result?
Is there a simple workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Echo` will help you see what has happened:

```
test[fu_] := 
 Plot[(-Derivative[-1][Function[t, fu] // Echo][t]), {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
test[fun[t]]
```

[image]

This behavior is discussed in the document:

[Modularity and the Naming of Things ▸ Variables in Pure Functions and Rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html#1131)

We also have a number of related posts in this site, for example:

[Unexpected variable renaming depending on form of a pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124435/1871)

[Is anonymous pure function a scoping construct?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124583/1871)

[Is the renaming mechanism of `With` flawed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119403/1871)

[Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/1871)

There should be more.

A simple way to avoid the renaming is, using `Apply` (`@@`) to *break* the pure function:

```
test[fu_] := 
 Plot[(-Derivative[-1][Function @@ {t, fu}][t]), {t, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: Clever idea to use `Echo`, have to remember it. Thanks for your answer! Still I don't understand why  `Plot`-function  evaluates without problems.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Are you asking why `Plot` still gives a plot in last case? If so, it's because `Function[t$,…]` is still a function. (Simpler example: `Derivative[-1][Function[aaa, t^2]]`. ) If you're asking why the renaming doesn't happen in 2nd case, it's because in that case you haven't defined the function `test`. The renaming is triggered by the nesting of `:=` and `Function`. See the table *Scoping constructs in the Wolfram Language* in the linked tutorial. As mentioned therein: "When you mix these constructs in any way, the Wolfram Language does appropriate renamings to avoid conflicts."

Comment: @xzcy Thank You very very much!