# Temporary symbol leaks into public context?

Tags: scoping, symbols, contexts

This phenomenon has confused me a long time. Consider the following package example,

```
BeginPackage["temp`"];

test;

test2;

Begin["`Private`"];

f[x_]:=
    test_:>{x,test};

f2[x_]:=
    test2_:>{test2};

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

where `test2` is for comparison.

Then in notebook evaluate the following test code with a fresh kernel,

```
<<temp`

Names["temp`*"]

??test$

??temp`test2$
```

[image]

It's weird that the temporary symbol `test$` leaks into the public context `` temp` `` .
Notice that:

- the leaked temporary symbol must have the same name as the public one;
- the local symbol `x` in the definition of `f` is necessary to repeat this behaviour.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's generated by the definition of `f`, but I can't explain it. Other than it's because of the `x` in the RHS of the `RuleDelayed[]`.

Comment: Some of the related Q&A: [(20766)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766), [(119403)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119403), [(124435)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124435) -- It's as though the system is anticipating the renaming to happen if ``temp`Private`f[3]`` should ever be called.

Comment: Leaking via Pattern naming is a common phenomenon. The name space for local pattern leads to unexpected results in replacements, regularly, if pattern symbols collide with DelayedSet symbols. It's good practice, to chose symbols locally with sight on the symbols around and don't use general replacements procedures, because Replace does not respect any algebra notation conventions.