# Defining an operator: Partially evaluate a Pure Function

Tags: functions, evaluation, pure-function, operators

I would like to define an operator that takes some parameters as input and returns a function. Here is an example:

```
operator[indexLists_] := Function[weights,Table[Total[weights[[indexLists[[i]]]]], {i, Length[indexLists]}]];
example = {{1, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 1}, {1, 2}, {6, 7}};
op1 = operator[example]
```

which returns

```
Function[weights$, Table[Total[
   weights$[[{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 1}, {1, 2}, {6, 7}}[[i]]]]], {i, Length[{{1, 2, 3}, {5, 2, 1}, {1, 2}, {6, 7}}]}]]
```

what I would want is a partially evaluated version, i.e.

```
op2 = Function[weights, {Total[weights[[{1, 2, 3}]]], Total[weights[[{5, 2, 1}]]], Total[weights[[{1, 2}]]], Total[weights[[{6, 7}]]]}]
```

Both op1 and op2 return functions that perform the same thing, e.g. when called with "Range[8]" as argument they return {6, 8, 3, 13}.

This is a toy example. In my real example, the function returned by the operator performs some complex transformation of the input parameter "weights" that I want to pre-compute in order to be more efficient when evaluating the function many times. I could not figure out how to get around to HoldAll attribute of the pure function.

Comment: This is related, but perhaps not an exact duplicate: [Replace function call with expression resulting from the symbolic evaluation of the function when defining a second function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30205/replace-function-call-with-expression-resulting-from-the-symbolic-evaluation-of) Admittedly the title of that question makes it hard to see the overlap, but the basic issue is similar.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive)/[`Activate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate):

```
operator[indexLists_] := Block[{weights},
    Activate @ Inactive[Function][
        weights,
        Table[Inactive[Total][Inactive[Part][weights,indexLists[[i]]]],{i,Length[indexLists]}]
    ]
]
```

Inactivating [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function) wasn't strictly necessary, but it prevented the variable `weights` from being modularized to `weights$`. Inactivating [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total) and one of the [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part) functions prevented undesired evaluations. Your example:

```
example = {{1,2,3},{5,2,1},{1,2},{6,7}};
op1 = operator[example]
```

> Function[weights, {Total[weights[[{1, 2, 3}]]], Total[weights[[{5, 2, 1}]]], 
>     Total[weights[[{1, 2}]]], Total[weights[[{6, 7}]]]}]

and

```
op1[Range[8]]
```

> {6, 8, 3, 13}

Answer (score 1):

An approach to circumvent the `HoldAll` attribute is to "inject" the expressions into `Function` after (partially) evaluating them:

```
operator[indexLists_] := 
 Block[{weights, f}, 
  Function[weights, #] & @Thread[f[weights, indexLists]] /. 
   f[xx__] :> Total[Part[xx]]]
```

Inside `Block`, I clear not only the variable `weights` but also an auxiliary `f` that is replaced at the very end with `Total[Part[...]]`. This replacement rule is one way to inject things into held expressions. Before that, I first create a slot `#` inside `Function` into which I insert the evaluated `Table` generated by the `indexList` argument to `operator`. This is where the temporary name `f` is used as a placeholder for the desired operation which can't be executed at that stage. It creates the necessary structure inside `Function` into which the replacement rule then inserts `Total[Part[...]]`.