# Function generating a rule with a Patterns: e.g. toRule[ lhs, rhs] into lhs[x_] -> rhs

Tags: replacement, argument-patterns

I want to create a rule as a function of `z` from a left and right hand side.  My (non-working) code and usage is:

```
toRule[l_, r_] := l[x_] -> r

toRule[f, a+b]
```

I want the output to be:

```
(* => f[x_] -> a + b*)
```

However: when I do this with the code above I get:

```
(* => f[x$_] -> a + b*)
```

Where is the $ coming from, and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it. For a quick fix try `toRule[l_, r_] := l[x_] -> #&@ r`

Comment: This is the same problem of excessive variable renamings as described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia). Use any of the constructs which fool this mechanism, such as `toRule[l_, r_] := Rule @@ {l[x_], r}` or `toRule[l_, r_] := Identity[Rule][l[x_], r]`, and everything is dandy. But, often such cases are a signal to reconsider what is it you are actually trying to do - the real need for such tricks is rare.

Comment: Thank you.  This appears to be the problem.  It sure appears to be a defect to me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do what you want is via the use of default values.

```
toRule[left_, right_, var_:x] := Rule[left @@ {var}, right]
```

or

```
Default[toRule] = x
toRule[left_, right_, var_.] := Rule[left @@ {var}, right]
```

They both work as intended as long as the left argument is the head of a function of the default variable var.

Comment: Thanks.  `ToRules[f, a+b, x_]` does indeed work.  I would guess it is because of the same sorts of trickery mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, toRule[f,a+b] should work too. If you are willing to specify the variable, then you could use the following call syntax: toRule[left_, right_, var_], with the same definition given above.