# Need to run evaluation 2 times

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, pure-function

Why does this only work after running the evaluation 2 times?

```
diff[var1_, y0_, funk_, {var2_, a_, b_}, N_] := ( 

 Module[{h},

  var1 := #1;
  var2 := #2;
  h = (b - a)/N;

  FoldList[var1 + h*funk &, y0, Range[a, b - h, h]] ])
```

Evaluation the first time

```
diff[y, 2, -t y^2, {t, 0., 2}, 20]
```

> ```
> {2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 
> 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 
> 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 
> 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 
> 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 
> 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 
> 0.1 #1^2 #2, #1 - 0.1 #1^2 #2}
> ```

Evaluation the second time

```
diff[y, 2, -t y^2, {t, 0., 2}, 20]
```

> ```
> {2, 2., 1.96, 1.88317, 1.77678, 1.6505, 1.51429, 1.37671, 1.24404, 1.12023,
>     1.00728, 0.905822, 0.815565, 0.735748, 0.665376, 0.603394, 0.548781, 0.500596, 
>     0.457994, 0.420238, 0.386684}
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is malformed code with some strange effects.  In the first evaluation `y` is substituted for `var1` in `var1 := #1` therefore after the first evaluation the global Symbol `y` has the assigned value `#1` (`Slot[1]`).  When the expression is evaluated a second time this value is substituted into the inner function `var1 + h*funk &` by the main definition for `diff` making it `#1 + h*funk &` and it then operates.

What were you attempting to do with this code?

---

I believe your desired functionality may be had by using named parameters in `Function` rather than `Slot` parameters.  Consider:

```
diff[var1_, y0_, funk_, {var2_, a_, b_}, N_] :=
  Module[{h},
   h = (b - a)/N;
   FoldList[Function[{var1, var2}, var1 + h*funk], y0, Range[a, b - h, h]]
  ]

diff[y, 2, -t y^2, {t, 0., 2}, 20] (* first evaluation *)
```

> ```
> {2, 2., 1.96, 1.88317, 1.77678, 1.6505, <<>> 0.386684}
> ```

You can ignore the red syntax highlighting which is warning of possible name collision because that happens to be what you want.  Note that [automatic renaming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/121) does take place here, but since the renaming is uniform in both the named `Function` parameters and the body that you inject (`funk_`) I do not believe this is a problem.  Here is a look at the `Function` produced that is used by `FoldList`:

```
diffX[var1_, y0_, funk_, {var2_, a_, b_}, N_] :=
 Module[{h},
  h = (b - a)/N;
  Function[{var1, var2}, var1 + h*funk]
 ]

diffX[y, 2, -t y^2, {t, 0., 2}, 20]
```

> ```
> Function[{y$, t$}, y$ + h$579 (-t$ y$^2)]
> ```

Observe that `t` has been renamed to `t$` in all appearances.

You may wish to add the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute to `diff`, as without it a global assignment to `y` or `t` will cause failure.

Comment: The list from the second evaluation is what i need to proceed. (The list is correct). What i tried to do is assaign the varibles (y and t) to #1 and #2, so it was possible to use with any "funk" input. (fx -t y^2)

Comment: @Punchline OK, I think I understand.  Give me a few minutes to write something useful.

Comment: Cool! It now works like it should - even though my coding skills need improving. Thanks

Comment: @Punchline You're welcome.