# Problem with Evaluate inside Module

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction, evaluation, scoping

**My problem**

I have a large system of differential equations which is automatically created, but to give you an easy example let's just say it is

```
eqs = {f'[x] == a[x]*g[x], g'[x] == -a[x]*f[x]};
```

As you can see, the system of equations contains the still undetermined function `a[x]`.
I want to numerically solve these equations for different functions `a[x]`, what I wrote is something like

```
solveMyEquation[a_] := Module[{foo, bar},
  foo = Flatten[{Evaluate[eqs], f[0] == 0, g[0] == 1}];
  bar = NDSolve[foo, {f, g}, {x, 0, 10}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]} /. bar], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

If I try to solve this using e.g. `solveMyEquation[1 &]`, I get a huge load of error messages, starting with

```
NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {a[x],f[x],g[x]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.
ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{(f^\[Prime])[x]==a[x] g[x],(g^\[Prime])[x]==-a[x] f[x],f[0]==0,g[0]==1},{f,g},{x,0,10}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
NDSolve::dsvar: 0.0002042857142857143` cannot be used as a variable.
```

**What I have tried**

The problem seems to be that the function `a[x]` is not inserted into `eqs`. That's what I was trying to achieve with the `Evaluate`, but apparently it doesn't work the way I thought it did.

The following obviously works fine:

```
solveMyEquation[a_] := Module[{foo, bar},
  foo = Flatten[{{f'[x] == a[x]*g[x], g'[x] == -a[x]*f[x]}, f[0] == 0, g[0] == 1}];
  bar = NDSolve[foo, {f, g}, {x, 0, 10}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]} /. bar], {x, 0, 10}]]
solveMyEquation[1 &]
```

But in my actual problem, the expression for `eqs` fills several pages and I don't like copy-pasting it (even though it does work).

Comment: Related thread [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39226/44141)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local variable `a` is taking precedence over the global `a` defined in `eqs`. There are multiple solutions suggested in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39226/44141). For the sake of completeness, I show here how to use one of the ideas by using [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html):

```
solveMyEquation[a_] :=  Module[{foo, bar}, 
 foo = Flatten[{Evaluate[eqs], f[0] == 0, g[0] == 1}];
 bar = NDSolve[foo /. Symbol@"a" -> a, {f, g}, {x, 0, 10}];
 Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]} /. bar], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

**EDIT:**

Of course, it would be better to have `eqs` such that we don't have to deal with variable conflicts, so if there is no way to influence how `eqs` is generated, we can season it a bit by converting to a pure function which we can then use inside our `Module`. To do this, we can make a simple function:

```
fixeqs[eq_] := Function[eq /. a -> #];
solveMyEquation[a_] := 
  Module[{foo, bar}, 
  foo = Flatten[{fixeqs[eqs]@a, f[0] == 0, g[0] == 1}];
  bar = NDSolve[foo, {f, g}, {x, 0, 10}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]} /. bar], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a nicer way, but I guess I'll go with this. Thanks!

Comment: I agree, it is best to not have a variable overlap to begin with. Updated the answer to reflect a new way.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: turn your `eqs` into a function of `a`, `f`, and `g`: the following works for me

```
eqns[a_, f_, g_] := {f'[x] == a[x]*g[x], g'[x] == -a[x]*f[x]};
solveMyEquation[a_] := 
 Module[{foo, bar}, 
  foo = Flatten[{eqns[a, f, g], f[0] == 0, g[0] == 1}];
  bar = NDSolve[foo, {f, g}, {x, 0, 10}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]} /. bar], {x, 0, 10}]]
solveMyEquation[1 &]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my actual problem, it would be a quite long parameter list to eqs as well as to several other functions I use for constructing eqs, though. I guess it would work, but I'd consider it ugly... I'll leave the question open for a while in hope for something else.