# Refering to local module variables

Tags: scoping

How can I do the following? I have code inside a Module such as `Module[{a1,a2,a3,a4}, code...]`. In this code I want to refer to these constants efficiently (for a large number of them) so I would construct them in ways such as `Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 4}]`. The important point is that they are constructed as `a1` (etc) after the module has done its renaming to a unique variable. So this does not work, see:

```
Module[{a1}, 
 MemberQ[Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 3}], a1]]
```

Is it possible to do this correctly? (By the way, this is almost the opposite question of [Refering to global variables inside modules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39226/refering-to-global-variables-inside-modules).)

---

As often, the time needed to formulating the question was enough to actually find a solution. While it isn't an answer to the question, the better way to avoid the whole problem is to assign multiple downvalues to one `a` , i.e. `a[1]`,`a[2]`,...

Comment: maybe `Block` instead of `Module`?

Comment: @kglr, thanks. I think I'd also consider this a full answer. Indeed not only does this work, I think it is the sensible solution. I have been following the advice of the wise Leonid Shifrin: "In practice, my advice would be to avoid using Block unless you know quite well why you need it." However, I do think that this is the type of situation that actually calls for a Block. Your answer inspired me to finally read up on Block, instead of dismissing it as less useful than Module.

Comment: Kvothe, I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Block` instead of `Module`:

```
Block[{a1}, MemberQ[Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 3}], a1]]
```

> True

From [Block >> Properties and Relations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Block.html):

- *Block localizes values only; it does not create new symbols*
- *Module creates new symbols*

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using `$ModuleNumber`.  However `a[1]`, `a[2]`,... is better

```
Module[{a1, a2, a3, mn = $ModuleNumber},
 MemberQ[Table[ToExpression[
    StringJoin["a", ToString[i], "$", ToString[mn]]], {i, 3}], a1]]
```

> True

Note, if `$ModuleNumber` is called outside the local brackets it needs to be decremented.

```
Module[{a1, a2, a3, mn},
 mn = $ModuleNumber - 1;
 MemberQ[Table[ToExpression[
    StringJoin["a", ToString[i], "$", ToString[mn]]], {i, 3}], a1]]
```

> True