# How to define function that can change patterns

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

Given time series data as follows:

```
data = 
  {{{2011, 1, 13}, 10}, {{2011, 2, 14}, 17}, {{2011, 3, 15}, 20}, 
   {{2012, 1, 16}, 30}, {{2012, 2, 17}, 40}};
```

Evaluating

```
Cases[data, {{year_, month_, day_}, val_} /; year == 2011]
```

will return the data that are in year 2011.

Are there any ways that I can define a function that can change the criteria of matching patterns?

For example,

```
TimeSelection[data_, pattern_] := Cases[data, {{year_, month_, day_}, val_} /; pattern]
```

If the pattern is `month == 2`, the return will only be the data in February.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your function would/should work, except for the fact that [automatic renaming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/121) is taking place due to nested scoping constructs (here `SetDelayed` and `Condition`).  Essentially *Mathematica* is trying to prevent a name collision, but that (shared names) is exactly what you need here.  You can see the problem using [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html):

```
TimeSelection[{"anything"}, month == 2] // Trace
```

> ```
> {TimeSelection[{anything},month==2],Cases[{anything},
>   {{year$_,month$_,day$_},val$_}/;month==2],{}}
> ```

Note that the pattern name `month` has been renamed to `month$`.  One simple work-around therefore is to use `month$` in your condition:

```
TimeSelection[data, month$ == 2]
```

> ```
> {{{2011, 2, 14}, 17}, {{2012, 2, 17}, 40}}
> ```

Another, more robust method, is to assemble the `Condition` expression at evaluation so your Pattern names do not explicitly appear inside that head as visible to `SetDelayed`:

```
TimeSelection[data_, pattern_] := 
  Cases[data, # /; pattern] & @ {{year_, month_, day_}, val_}

TimeSelection[data, month == 2]
```

> ```
> {{{2011, 2, 14}, 17}, {{2012, 2, 17}, 40}}
> ```

The mechanism of this and other work-arounds is discussed in the post linked at the top of this answer.  (`Function` with `Slot` does not suffer from automatic renaming, but `Function` with named parameters does.)