# What is so special about variable s$?

Tags: symbolic

I found a nice bug in *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0. Could anyone check to reproduce it?

Create a file `temp.txt` with one line:

```
Attributes[s$] = {Temporary}
```

Load it into *Mathematica* with `<<`.

Now calculate:

```
Sum[x^(-n)*y^n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

*Mathematica* stops responding and the only option is to quit the kernel. You can't interrupt or abort.

Now change `s` to `a` or `b` in the file and repeat the above. It works!

Next put the line

```
Attributes[s$] = {Temporary}
```

directly into the notebook and calculate the sum. It works!

What is so special about temporary variable `s$` loaded from the file?

I used a temporary variable `s$` in one of my functions and then saved 
the function to the file. *Mathematica* added the above line to the file. 
Everything stopped working.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I've actually had weird situations where the choice of dummy variable in the integration changed the result of the symbolic integral, with certain choices giving the correct answer and other choices causing the kernel to time out.

Comment: Mathematica uses renaming to localize variables.  In certain situations `s` will be renamed to `s$` to avoid name collisions (though *not* in `Module`).  You should *never* use such names in your code or you're risking to break things.

Comment: I always use Module for functions. Why it works in the notebook and not from the file ? What a difference between "s" and "a" ? If I can use "a" and not "s", it should be documented and this is unacceptable. It works fine in Mathematica 7, by the way.

Comment: @Vlad As I said you should never use the name `s$`, as this is reserved for internal operations.  If you do, you are just asking for trouble.  Did you explicitly use this symbol (`s$`) in your code?

Comment: Ok, I started checking all letters. It works for "a" and "b", but does not work for "c" and "d". Shall we divide the alphabet into allowed and forbidden temporary variables ? And the variable "s" is never used in the above example.

Comment: @Vlad This is not a Q/A site, not a place to rant.  Please make sure that you ask a clear and answerable question.  If your question was, "is this a bug and how do I work around it?", then you got the answer: if you used `s$` then it's not a bug, it's user error.  If you didn't then maybe.  Yet you fail to tell us if you did or didn;t.

Comment: @Szabolcs Does your emphatic *never* include e.g. [this use?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41642/121) I've done that more than a few times without apparent problem, but maybe I haven't thought this through.

Comment: @Szabolcs I clearly said that the variable "s" is not used in the code I showed. I define "s" as a temporary variable and only use variables "x", "y" and "n". It stops working.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think that, if your use stopped working or happened to eventually break something, it wouldn't be a MMA bug, but a risk you were willing to take

Comment: @Vlad, as to the difference, I think at least in the notebook the line where you set the attributes shouldn't do anything. Because since it is `Temporary` the symbol should get removed instantly. Perhaps that's not the case if it was defined in the file? I haven't tried

Comment: ...but it doesn't remove it, so I guess I'm confused and wrong about something

Comment: @Vlad Simply mentioning it to Mathematica counts as using it.  However, what I asked you was: did you use `s` or `s$`?  The two are two different things.  In the example you posted you are using `s$`, which as I said is a mistake and there's no surprise that it breaks Sum's or Get's internals.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd say that's a hack which I might also use for a one time quick and dirty solution ...  It's also true that Mathematica has problems because of how it handles name collisions and localizations.  However I wouldn't do [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41640/how-to-define-function-that-can-change-patterns/41642#41642) in a project where there's any expectation of reliability, such as MATLink ... or even code I regularly use for my research.

Comment: @Rojo It does remove it during notebook session if you set `$HistoryLength = 0;` and removes even without this when the line `Attributes[s$] = {Temporary}` is imported from a file using `Get`.

Comment: I filed a bug report for this. Best advice remains: Don't use variables that end with $. Too much chance of confusing the scoping mechanism.