# How to explain the behavior of Rule inside these functions

Tags: functions, evaluation

I'm trying to define a function that takes an expression and spits out a pure function involving a replacement rule of that function's variable. An example would be a function `f` such that `f[x^2]` returns `x^2 /. x -> # &` (let's just stick with single-variable function for simplicity's sake).

I have written 2 functions, both aim to do just that. Now, their pure function outputs do work when applied to something else (see last input of block code), but they themselves don't display in the form that I'd like:

```
(* 1 *)    
Clear[f1]
f1[expr_] := Module[{var},
  var = First@Variables[expr];
  expr /. var -> # &]

f1[x^2]
(* x^2 /. var$77097 -> #1 & *)


(* 2 *)
Clear[f2]
f2[expr_] := expr /. First@Variables[expr] -> # &

f2[x^2]
(* x^2 /. First[Variables[x^2]] -> #1 & *)


{f1[x^2][3], f2[x^2][3]}
(* {9, 9} *)
```

It seems like `Rule` holds the evaluation of the left hand side, which I don't really know why. Adding `Evaluate` to the left hand side did not help. I tried reading the documentation for `Rule` but couldn't find any relevant information on this behavior. One of its attributes is `SequenceHold`. Could that be a contribution? Also, if anyone could help me understand the result I got for each of those modules I'd really appreciate it. I'm very fuzzy on evaluation order inside `Rule` and `Module`.

Lastly, how can I build such a function mentioned in the beginning of my question?

Comment: `f2[expr_] := With[{var = First@Variables[expr]}, expr /. var -> # &]`

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you help me understand why `With` will display the correct result but not `Module`? Please feel free to post that as an answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: I believe this issue has already been well covered on this site, therefore I wish to close this question as a duplicate unless I can be convinced otherwise.  Please review these and tell me which seems closest: [(10086)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10086)
[(13757)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13757)
[(20766)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766)
[(34345)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34345)
[(41640)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41640)

Comment: I think the closest Q&A to this (13757 and 20766) involve using `Function` within `Module` where the local variable in `Module` conflicts with the formal parameter of the `Function`. I think my question is more of a conflict between a `Module` variable and the _body_ of an inner `Function`, which won't let that variable evaluate due to `Function`'s `HoldAll` attribute (I think that's what the reason was). Leonid's [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) in this Q&A comes really close to explaining the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "inject" that variable by grabbing it with `With`. It then gets put into the body of the `With` verbatim, hence it gets inside the `Function` in the desired form.

```
f2[expr_] := With[{var = First@Variables[expr]}, expr /. var -> # &]

f2[x^2]

(* Out[79]= x^2 /. x -> #1 & *)
```

This can also be done in the way you had tried, with a bit of work to get past the held arguments to `Function`. In effect we inject the variable after rather than before we create the function.

```
f1[expr_] := Module[{var},
  expr /. var -> # & /. var -> First@Variables[expr]]

f1[x^2]

(* Out[87]= x^2 /. x -> #1 & *)
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer! So were the results that I got due to the `HoldAll` attribute of `Function`? If so, why could `With` seemingly bypass that hold but not `Module`?

Comment: Okay [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) by @LeonidShifrin seems to explain it: `It is instructive to trace the execution of f. You will notice that[, with Using With, the] sum gets replaced by its value very early on, before the body starts evaluating. This is quite unlike Module, where variable entries get replaced by their values in the process of evaluation, just as it woud normally happen were the variables global.` I wonder if this distinction is mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: It's mentioned, though not quite in this way, under Scope, Applications, and Properties & Relations. That is to say it is documented but this "pre-injection" aspect is not, in my view, heavily emphasized.

Comment: Thank you! It does get mentioned in `With` documentation quite a bit.