# StringReplace, ReplaceAll and Rule interact in a bizarre way

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation, scoping, rule

I have the following pair of things:

```
ClearAll[foo, labeledFoo];

labeledFoo = {"FooBarBazQuux", foo};
```

This works like you'd expect:

```
labeledFoo /. hdr_String :> 
  StringReplace[hdr, l_?LowerCaseQ ~~ U_?UpperCaseQ :> l <> " " <> U]

(* {"Foo Bar Baz Quux", foo} *)
```

So does this:

```
labeledFoo /. hdr_String :> 
  StringReplace[hdr, l_?LowerCaseQ ~~ U_?UpperCaseQ :> l <> " " <> U] /.
    {hdr_String, x_} :> (hdr -> x)

(* "Foo Bar Baz Quux" -> foo *)
```

Heck, even this works:

```
labeledFoo /. {hdr_String, x_} :> (Rule @@ {StringReplace[hdr, 
  l_?LowerCaseQ ~~ U_?UpperCaseQ :> l <> " " <> U], x})

(* "Foo Bar Baz Quux" -> foo *)
```

This, though, doesn't work at all:

```
labeledFoo /. {hdr_String, x_} :> (StringReplace[hdr, 
 l_?LowerCaseQ ~~ U_?UpperCaseQ :> l <> " " <> U] -> x)

(* "Fo" ~~ l <> " " <> U ~~ "a" ~~ l <> " " <> U ~~ "a" ~~  
  l <> " " <> U ~~ "uux" -> foo *)
```

I really have no idea what's going on. This is so weird that I feel like I must be missing a simple syntax error, but all the other things that **do** work make me doubt that.

Comment: In fact, this behavior was discussed before, in [this thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Dec/msg00578.html). It only took me 4.5 years to find a decent explanation (I completely forgot about that thread when answering, found this rather accidentally just now).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Preamble

What happens can be understood when we recall that `Rule` is a scoping construct.
The general issues related to variable renamings in scoping constructs have been considered in more details in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia/20776#20776).

#### General

Now, to this particular case. When the code runs, the external `RuleDelayed` considers the situation "dangerous" and performs variable renamings for your `l` and `U` variables.You end up with the code like this:

```
StringReplace["FooBarBazQuux",l$_?LowerCaseQ~~U$_?UpperCaseQ:>l<>" "<>U]
```

which can be seen using `Trace`. This means that the `l` and `U` on the r.h.s. are no longer coupled to the patterns on the l.h.s., thus the result.

In the first 3 cases, this doesn't happen, because the outer `RuleDelayed` can not "sense" the inner scoping construct (`Rule` in this case) - which is true even in the case `Rule @@ {...}`. Therefore, it does not perform the renamings. The reason why it does not care about the inner `RuleDelayed` is that they are completely decoupled, since no pattern variable from the outer `RuleDelayed` is used in the inner `RuleDelayed`.

This is not the case in the last example, where the more external `Rule` becomes coupled to the outermost `RuleDelayed` via the `x` variable. And, presumably because the system is acting rather silly in this case and considers the pattern variables `l` and `U` to belong to the `Rule` rather than the inner `RuleDelayed` (see also below for a bit more on that), we get a problem.

#### Simpler example, and a possible explanation

Exactly the same situation happens in this, somewhat simpler example:

```
{{1, 2}, 3} /. {x_List, y_Integer} :>
  Rule[
     Replace[x, {l_Integer, u_Integer} :> l + u],
     y
  ]

(* l + u -> 3 *)
```

But what I think is really happening, is that in doing these renamings, the system acts rather silly. It interprets `l_` and `u_` *not as parts of inner `RuleDelayed`*, but as parts of the outer `Rule`. This is why it breaks the scoping / binding of inner `RuleDelayed` - because it is not clever enough to see that those pattern variables are localized by that inner `RuleDelayed` - it rather thinks that they belong to a more external `Rule`. And it only renames the variables inside patterns, because if you have

```
{x_, x+1} -> x^2
```

then `x` in `x+1` will of course be taken from enclosing environment, and thus there is no need to localize / rename it.

#### Removing the lexical coupling

The final thing here: let us prove that the problem we have is due to a lexical coupling, in that external `Rule` is coupling the inner patterns with outer `RuleDelayed` via the `y` variable (in my example, and `x` in yours):

```
{{1, 2}, 3} /. {x_List, y_Integer} :>
  Block[{yy = y},
    Rule[
      Replace[x, {l_Integer, u_Integer} :> l + u],
      yy]
  ]

(* 3 -> 3 *)
```

Now, all is fine and dandy, since `Block` is not a lexical scoping construct, and we decouple the outer and inner `RuleDelayed`, even though `Rule` is present. Try using `y` in `Rule[Replace[...], y]` instead, and remove the `Block` - and we
are back to the same code as before. If you use `With` or `Module` in place of `Block`, the problem is still there - since they are both lexical scoping constructs, they will do the renamings in the same way as `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: Requisite link to our co-authored answer: [(20776)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! Indeed, very relevant.

Comment: Accepted. I've been burned by the perfidy of `RuleDelayed` rewriting stuff before, but it never occurred to me it would do the same thing to the LHS of a plain old `Rule`.

Comment: @Pillsy [1/2] Thanks for the accept! Yep, I did not see this one before either. But it is clear that it would rename the variables inside patterns for l.h.s. of either inner `Rule` or `RuleDelayed`, as long as they are syntactically coupled via some common variable (as in the last example of yours). The problem here is that the external `RuleDelayed` does not recognize the correct localization of `l`and `U` variables - it thinks they belong to `Rule`.

Comment: @Pillsy [2/2] Then, it does renamings for all variables inside *patterns* on the l.h.s. of the rule, which, in my simpler example, is `Replace[x, {l_Integer, u_Integer} :> l + u]`. And it does not care about the non-pattern occurences of `l` and `u` (r.h.s. of inner `RuleDelayed` here), inside the l.h.s. of `Rule`, because, as I said, it thinks that `l_` and `u_` patterns belong to `Rule`. So, it messes up the bindings of inner `RuleDelayed`. Perhaps, this may be called a bug. Also, not that it is only happens when outer and inner rules are "lexically coupled" by some common variable.