# Strange behavior with Cases and Position with SetDelayed

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, scoping

I feel like I must be missing something simple and obvious here, but this has me scratching my head.

This works as expected:

```
list = {f[a], f[b]};
Cases[list, f[x_] :> x] -> Position[list, f[_]]

(* {a, b} -> {{1}, {2}} *)
```

However, this does not:

```
fun[list_] := Cases[list, f[x_] :> x] -> Position[list, f[_]];
fun[list]

(* {x, x} -> {{1}, {2}} *)
```

Is this a bug, or have I just not had enough coffee today?

Comment: And yet `fun[list_] := Cases[list, f[x_] :> x]` will yield `{a, b}`. And `fun[list_] := Cases[list, f[x$_] :> x$] -> Position[list, f[_]]` works. Someone else will have to explain the details here, because I don't quite get it.

Comment: Ok, the `fun[list_] := Cases[list, f[x$_] :> x$] -> Position[list, f[_]]` really has me baffled, but at least it's an easy workaround for my problem. I'm just curious, why did adding a `$` come to mind as something to try?

Comment: You can even simplify the workaround to `fun[list_] := Cases[list, f[x_] :> x$] -> Position[list, f[_]]` and it seems to work for me, as MMA adds its own `$` to the first x in the Cases pattern.

Comment: @N.J.Evans has it: I `Trace`d the evaluation of your `fun[list]` and noticed that during that process, `Cases[list, f[x$_] :> x]` shows up, so the replacement wasn't going to work.

Comment: I don't know what you `Trace`'d but it isn't what I wrote unless there is a version difference. Did you `ClearAll[fun]`? The replacement works exactly because of the result you give. By adding an extra `$` to the `x` after the `:>` in `Cases` I forced the replacement to happen, because MMA added the `$` to `f[x_]`.

Comment: `fun[list_List] := Cases[list, g[y_] :> y$] -> Position[list, g[_]];
Trace@fun[list]` gives me `{{list,{g[a],g[b]}},fun[{g[a],g[b]}],Cases[{g[a],g[b]},g[y$_]:>y$]->Position[{g[a],g[b]},g[_]],{{g[y$_]:>y$,g[y$_]:>y$},Cases[{g[a],g[b]},g[y$_]:>y$],{a,b}},{Position[{g[a],g[b]},g[_]],{{1},{2}}},{a,b}->{{1},{2}},{a,b}->{{1},{2}}}`

Comment: @N.J.Evans: Your solution is fine: I was commenting on why the *OP*'s version didn't work. `Trace`-ing the OP's `fun[list]` showed `Cases[list, f[x$_] :> x]`, which is why I tried `Cases[list, f[x$_] :> x$]`. I still don't understand why this behavior occurs.

Comment: I missed the 'has it' : /

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### What's happening

This is not simple by any means. You have encountered another instance of a general situation with lexical scope leaks / emulation / over-protection by symbol renaming. The case at hand is pretty similar to the one discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46611), so you can read the detailed explanation of this behavior in my answer there.

Roughly speaking, outer lexical scoping constructs (`RuleDelayed` in the linked dicsussion, and its analog for implicit global rule application here), try to protect the inner bindings from destructive changes, but mis-interpret their pieces and instead destroy yet inner bindings in the process. We have to fool that mechanism somehow, to avoid that.

### Workarounds

#### The `"StrictLexicalScoping"` system option

Thanks to the hard work of Daniel Lichtblau, we now have a system option named `"StrictLexicalScoping"`, which, when set to `True`, fixes many such cases, including the one at hand. You have to execute this:

```
SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True]
```

*before* you enter the definition of your function, and then it will work as intended.

#### Fooling the protection mechanism explicitly

In your case, here is one possible such work-around that is reasonably clean:

```
fun[list_] := 
   With[{rule = Rule}, 
      rule[Cases[list, f[x_] :> x], Position[list, f[_]]]
   ];
```

There are many more variations of it. What really matters is that `SetDelayed` and then the internal rule application engine (internal analog of `RuleDelayed` for global rules) don't *see* external `Rule` during the rule application.

This is surely not something that would first come to mind, though :)

### Additional references

Here are a few additional links relevant to this discussion

- [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766)
- [Exhaustive examples of variable replacement due to nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48639)
- [I define a variable as local to a module BUT then the module uses its global value! Why?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72758/81)

Comment: `fun[list_List] := 
  Evaluate@(Cases[list, g[x_] :> x] -> Position[list, g[_]]);` also works.

Comment: @N.J.Evans I don't think so. It has some other symbol `g` in it, and `Evaluate` just causes its r.h.s. to evaluate immediately, so I don't see how this could possibly work. It didn't work for me anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I was using `g` as my head because I had an `f` defined somewhere else. It does seem to work for me though.

Comment: @N.J.Evans But for me this didn't work even if I replaced `f -> g` everywhere: `fun2[list_List] := 
  Evaluate@(Cases[list, g[x_] :> x] -> Position[list, g[_]]); fun2[{g[a], g[b]}]`.

Comment: That's pretty bizarre, because I just restarted my kernel to make sure everything was ok, and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @N.J.Evans: When I run your version in your first comment or the version in Leonid's last comment, I get `{ } -> { }`.

Comment: Maybe it's good to mention that `SetSystemOptions["StrictLexicalScoping" -> True]` solves this one too.

Comment: Well, either I'm losing my mind or 10.0.1 on OSX is not acting like everybody else's. I copied @Leonid Shifrin 's code exactly and it's still working.

Comment: @Szabolcs Strange, this is the first thing I tried, and it didn't work. Now I haved tried again and it worked. Will check a few more times, if this works reliably, I will mention this, sure.

Comment: @Szabolcs The things is, it turns out, that you have to switch that option on *before* defining the function, even though inspection of the `DownValues` yields the same expression in either case.

Comment: `fun[list_] := 
 Thread@Rule @@ {Cases[list, f[x_] :> x], Position[list, f[_]]}` ?

Comment: @belisarius I mentioned in my edited post that there are many possibilities. Yours is surely one of them. What matters is that the relevant consructs won't be able to detect `Rule` at the time they act. And you probably don't even need `Thread`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans. That is very strange, because I am *also* running 10.0.1 on OSX (10.6), and it returns `{}->{}`. Also on MMA 8.0.1 OSX 10.6. Also on MMA 10.0.1 on OSX 10.10.4.

Comment: Ok. Now it's fine. It looks like when I use `Evaluate` if `list` has a global definition, and `list` is the same name as the variable used in `fun2[list_]` then `Evaluate` evaluates the expression using the global definition of `list`, which is precisely equivalent to OP's first case, making it look like the function was working. Even after restarting my kernel, `list` was defined globally as per OP's example, causing the confusion.