# Inconsistent application of replacement rule

Tags: replacement

I want to use a replacement rule to change `log[var]` into `var` inside a function.  A minimal example follows.  In one case it works; in the other it doesn't.  Could someone explain the difference and how to fix in the second case?

```
unks = {log[n]};

foo1[x_] := Table[(unk /. log[var_] -> var) -> 5, {unk, unks}];
foo2[x_] := Table[(unk /. log[var_] -> var) -> x, {unk, unks}];

foo1[5]
(* {n -> 5} -- good *)
foo2[5]
(* {var -> 5} -- bad *)
```

Applying `Trace` shows that the bad `foo2` contains `log[var$_] -> var`, which seems like the source of the problem.  What's that `$` doing there?

Comment: Looks like the `x_` is causing the lexical scoping mechanism to come into play but the `HoldFirst` on `Table` is breaking that. Check out this: ``foo3[x_] := With[{reps={log[var_] :> var}}, Table[(unk/.reps)->x, {unk, unks}]]``

Comment: Also just gonna throw it out there since I think chances are good you know it already, but you're good on the fact that this is probably not the most less efficient way to do this, right? Better would be to do a more targeted `Replace[..., rule, {1}]` on `unks` first I imagine. Or if you need it deeper just to the `/.` there first or do a `Replace[..., rule, {1, Infinity}]` or something along those lines.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Don't assume anything about my programming knowledge!  But in my real problem, I've already got something like `{log[n] -> some stuff, log[m] -> some other stuff}` that I need to transform to `{n -> some (slightly different) stuff, m -> some other (slightly different) stuff}`.

Comment: might be a place where something like ``Thread[Replace[Keys[#], log[n_]:>n, {1}]->Values[#]]&`` might be the least likely to have side effects. Alternately create your replacement rules *first* with `Dispatch` to get most of the benefit of vectorizing the call.

Comment: @b3m2a1 The `HoldFirst` of `Table` doesn't seem to be the issue: `1 /. x_ -> ((var_ -> var) -> x)` returns `(var$_ -> var) -> 1`, which is already broken. From a few quick tests, it seems that all the rules in the example are needed for it to return strange results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same issue as described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91922/81) (and in references therein). I suggest to read that answer and the linked discussions for an explanation of why this happens.

The workaround can be also the same as mentioned there:

```
foo2[x_] := 
   With[{rule = Rule},
      Table[rule[(unk /. log[var_] -> var), x], {unk, unks}]
   ]
```

So that now

```
foo2[5]

(* {n -> 5} *)
```

Basically, it fools `RuleDelayed` (the one that results from `SetDelayed`, in `DownValues[foo2]`), so that it does not recognise the inner rule as such, and so does not rename `var` in one part of the inner rule during the rule application.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the detailed explanation of what's actually going on.

Comment: @ChrisK Was glad to help. Thanks for the accept.