# Problem with Manipulate after declaring pure function with Hold

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics3d, dynamic, mesh

I'm trying to illustrate the generation of the conic curves with a plane and a cone surface in ContourPlot3D, when I make a static plane there is no problem, and the intersection curve was generated as in [this documentation example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/HighlightTheIntersectionOfTwoSurfaces.html), the code is:

```
Clear[h, g];
h = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;
g = z - 4;
ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, h - g]}, 
 MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]]
```

[image: Correct, but static, circumference of intersection]

In order to make a dynamic view of the movement of the cut plane, I've tried with this code:

```
Clear[h, g];
h = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;
g = z - a;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ Hold[{x, y, z}, h - g]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]], {a, -1.8,
   1.8}]
```

But, get this error:

*MeshFunctions::invmeshf: MeshFunctions->Function[{x,y,z},h-g] must be a pure function or a list of pure functions.*

I've tried to Hold also the variable `a` of the Manipulate:

```
Clear[h, g, a];
h = x^2 + y^2 - z^2;
g = z - a;
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[{h == 0, g == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function @@ Hold[{a, x, y, z}, h - g]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]], {a, -1.8,
   1.8}]
```

and get now this error:

*MeshFunctions::invmeshf: MeshFunctions->Function[{FE`a$$445,x,y,z},h-g] must be a pure function or a list of pure functions.*

I don't know if I need to use ReleaseHold in some part of the code.

I've tried also with [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51522/defining-a-pure-function-involving-a-function-argument), obtaining a code like this:

```
cutplane := z - a;

SetAttributes[surface, HoldFirst]

surface[c_] := 
 ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, c == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 
   1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> 
   Function @@ Hold[{a, x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - c], 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Black}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.9], None}, BoundaryStyle -> None]

Manipulate[surface[cutplane], {a, -1, 1}]
```

But, I've obtained a figure like this that doesn't change.

[image: Another option that hasn't worked]

**How can I get a dynamic animation that shows this circumference intersections of the cone and plane?**

Comment: Put the functions **inside**: `Manipulate[ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, z - a == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, (x^2 + y^2 - z^2) - (z - a)]}, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]], {a, -1.8, 1.8}]`. The `a` inside the `Manipulate[]` is a *different symbol* from the `a` in the expressions defined outside it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well. Is there any form of declare the functions outside?

Comment: Linked topic should address the essence of your question but let me know if you, or anyone disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Turning J.M.'s comment and your comment into an answer, this is one of many, many ways to declare the function outside of the `Manipulate`

```
surf[a_] :=
 ContourPlot3D[
  {x^2 + y^2 - z^2 == 0, z - a == 0},
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
  MeshFunctions ->
   {Function[{x, y, z}, (x^2 + y^2 - z^2) - (z - a)]}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[Orange, Opacity[0.5], Specularity[White, 30]]
  ]

Manipulate[
 surf[a], {a, -1.8, 1.8}
 ]
```