# How to inject segments of code into functions defined by SetDelayed

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, scoping

I need to define a set of functions that are written in terms of common but lengthy expressions.  To effect this, I want to inject abbreviations for such expressions into the RHS of `SetDelayed` of multiple functions.  Something like this:

```
Clear[f, g];
Module[{abbrev = Sum[int[i], {i, 1, n}]},
  f[n_] := abbrev + y;
  g[n_] := abbrev^2;
  (*and so on*)
]
```

But it doesn't work.  First, the `n_` in the LHS is failing to match the `n` in the RHS.  Second, the kernel first evaluates the RHS of `abbrev` before injecting it into the RHSs of `f` and `g`.  In my program, that consumes time that could otherwise be saved.

What can I do to solve these problems?

Comment: `With` isn't working on my computer (*Mathematica* 10.2 on Mac OS X).  What version are you using?

Comment: @QuantumDot what are int and y terms in your code?

Comment: `int[i]` is a recursively defined symbolic function (the result is usually a polynomial plus some logarithms), `y` is a similar object (polynomial+logs) but known explicitly (no recursive code).

Comment: Ok, here is one way: `(f[n_] := # + y;
   g[n_] := #^2;) &[
 Sum[int[i], {i, 1, n}]
 ]` there should be a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Not the one I've thought about but I think it's good enough: [20766](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

Comment: Above you say `With` isn;t working on your computer. This would normally be done using `With`. Can you show us what you get?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Input `f[3]` gives `Sum[int[i],{i,1,n}]+y`.  The `n` didn't get replaced by `3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how robust this is. It is quick and dirty so to speak.

```
With[{abbrev := Sum[int[i], {i, 1, n$}]},
 f[n_] := abbrev + y;
 g[n_] := abbrev^2
 (*and so on*)]
```

[image]

...but I think @kuba's link provides better alternatives.

**Edit**

Such an alternative includes:

```
Clear[f, g];
Module[{abbrev := Sum[int[i], {i, 1, n}]},
 SetDelayed @@ {f[n_], abbrev + y};
 g[n_] := abbrev^2]
```

Where you do not have to modify the `n` with dollar signs. The explanation for why this works is given in the post by Mr Wizard and Leonid.