# Odd problem with `Module` and `Block`

Tags: scoping

I found some bizarre phenomena in my code. While I'm using `Module` in my function, the result is incompatible with which I did outside `Module`, and when I replaced `Module` with `Block` it went back to normal. I don't know why.

**Edit:**

Now the problem becomes this:

```
Module[{a,b},
a=Sin[x];
b[x_]=a;
b[y]
]
```

doesn't give `Sin[y]`, while `Block` gives `Sin[y]`.

Comment: @Kuba I have found the problem. It seems that my attmption `ϕ[x_] = ϕx` to make `ϕ` a pure function failed, so all the following `ϕ`s are function of `x`. When I change to `Block`, it seems fine again. Can you help me up with this?

Comment: Many thanks for the edit. Now it is clear you should read this: [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478) or just use the solution - `Set @@ {b[x_], a}`

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot. That solved my problem. And really sorry about the inconvenience I brought earlier.

Comment: No worries, it happens, what doesn't happen so often is what you did with the edit so thanks.