# Using Position[] inside a Module

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, scoping

I have a dataset with missing or wrong values. A module should replace those values so that the dataset length is preserved. For identifying the *positions to be replaced* I use `Position[]`.

Here is some data

```
data = {1, 2, 0, 4, , 6, "", 8} (* test set *);
criterList = {0, "", Null} (* selection criteria *);
```

Outside a `Module` it works correctly like this

```
temp = Or @@ Map[u == # &, criterList];
Position[data, u_ /; Evaluate@temp]
```

> ```
> {{3}, {5}, {7}}
> ```

The positions of *values to be replaced* are correctly identified.

However, inside a Module the same Code doesn't evaluate as above:

```
posMod[data_, criterList_] := Module[{u, res},
     temp = Or @@ Map[u == # &, criterList];
     Print[temp];
     Print["a)  ", Position[data, u_ /; Evaluate@temp]]   (* Why doesnt it work? *);
     Print["b)  ", Position[data, u_ /; {u == 0 || u == "" || u == Null}]] (* temp evaluated *);
     Print["c)  ", Position[data, u_ /; Evaluate[Or @@ Map[u == # &, criterList]]  ]] (*just copied *);
     ]

posMod[data, criterList]
```

> a)      {}
>       b)      {}
>       c)      {{3},{5},{7}}

Why does a) and b) not evaluate like c)?

Comment: This boils down to why `Module[{u}, {u, u_, u_ /; u}]` returns what it returns. Aside of the main question, you can use `Replace[data, Alternatives@@cri -> whatever, {1}]`

Comment: for (b)  use `u_ /. u == 0 || u == "" || u == Null` instead of `u_ /; {u == 0 || u == "" || u == Null}`?

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for giving the hint for Alternatives. I'd like to replace the value by e.g. the Mean of the nearest non-matching neighbors.

Comment: for (a) `Position[data, Alternatives @@ criterList]`?

Comment: use `Block` instead  of `Module`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Understanding what is going on

`Condition` seems to be considered a scoping construct and issues with automatic renaming apply.

It is a good idea to read this topic with understanding: [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

So essentially `u` in `temp` is not the same as `u` in `u_ /; ...` as the first one was scoped and the second on is treated by `Module` as an inner scoping construct and left alone.

Include `Print[u : _ /; Evaluate@temp]` to see

> ```
> u_ /; u$6121==0 || u$6121== " " || u$6121==Null
> ```

Let's take a closer look:

```
Module[{u, f}, Column@{ u,   Module[{u}, u],   u_ /; u,   u_ /; f + u,   }]
```

> ```
> u$8962
> u$8963
> u_/;u
> u$_/;f$8962+u$
> ```

1st line shows scoped `u`

2nd line shows that the outer module left inner's module `u` alone, otherwise we would see `u$8962$8963`

3rd line shows that here `u` is left alone too

4th line shows that `u` is replaced with `$u`, just in case, because another scoped variable appears in condition's body. This often causes confusion as shown in linked topic.

#### Why does a) and b) not evaluate like c)?

```
Module[{u}, Column@{
   u_ /; Evaluate@temp,
   u_ /; {u == 0 || u == "" || u == Null},
   u_ /; Evaluate[Or @@ Map[u == # &, criterList]]
}]
```

> ```
> u_/;u$6121==0||u$6121==||u$6121==Null
> u_/;{u==0||u==||u==Null}
> u_/;u==0||u==||u==Null
> ```

a) because of the issue explained above
b) because the condition test results in a List `{...}` not a `True/False`
c) everything is fine because `u` was not scoped by `Module` as it *saw* it being internal to `Condition`.

#### What to do?

```
Replace[data, Alternatives@@criterList-> whatever, {1}]
```