# Immediate Function Definition inside a Module

Tags: functions, scoping

In mathematica, it is possible to perform [immediate definition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) of a function where the dependent variable is not explicitly mentioned on the RHS. For example:

```
f1[xval_] := yval xval;
f2[xval_, yval_] = f1[xval] (*Immediate definition since cant use delayed due to yval*);
f2[10, 20]
```

One obtains the desired output of `200`. However, if I try to do the same in Module, the behavior is quite different:

```
ff[x1_, y1_] := Module[{x = x1, y = y1, f1, f2, yval},
 f1[xval_] := yval xval;
 f2[xval_, yval_] = f1[xval];
 f2[x1, y1]];
ff[10, 20]
```

When I try to run this, the output of `ff[10,20]` is `10 yval$166783` instead of `200`. I was wondering if there a way to get the same behavior that one gets without a module in this case? Of course, one solution is to use `yval` as the dependent variable of `f1` i.e. `f1[xval,yval]` instead of just `f1[xval]`. However, I have several lines of code before the definition of `f2` and adding `yval` as the dependent variable for each such line will involve too much effort.

Comment: You can use `Block` instead of `Module`. You have to read up on how scoping works in order to understand why. I also suspect that there is a better solution to your problem, but that would be another question that would have to explain what problem you are trying to solve is and where this problem is coming.

Comment: I think this boils down to: [20766](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478).