# pure Function[ ] named formal parameters

Tags: evaluation, pure-function

I am trying to setup a bunch of pure Functions in particular with an identical rahter long parameter list.

```
({a, b, c, d, e, f} \[Function] a + b)[r, s, t, u, v, w]
({a, b, c, d, e, f} \[Function] a*f)[r, s, t, u, v, w]
({a, b, c, d, e, f} \[Function] a*b/c)[r, s, t, u, v, w]
```

this works as expected:

```
r+s
r w
(r s)/t
```

Now I would like to put the formal parameter List in a variable:

```
pl = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
(Evaluate@pl \[Function] a + b)[r, s, t, u, v, w]
(Evaluate@pl \[Function] a*f)[r, s, t, u, v, w]
(Evaluate@pl \[Function] a*b/c)[r, s, t, u, v, w]
```

So far this works too an gives the sam result as above.

But there is a problem with the localization of the formal parameters.
If I e.g. assign a value to the global Symbol a:

```
a=42;
```

I get an Error:

```
Function::flpar: Parameter specification {42,b,c,d,e,f} in Function[{42,b,c,d,e,f},a+b] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.
```

Any hints how to solve this problem?
Have already tried various combinations of the usual suspects (Hold, Symbol, ...)

Kind Regards Robert

Ok, very close related to the first question I got a second one.

How can I get the SymbolName's of the Symbol's listed in pl? The need for this feature is e.g. to form a Table with TableForm and TableHeadings -> {None, pl}

```
a = 42;
pl := {a, b, c, d, e, f};

TableForm[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}}, TableHeadings -> {None, pl}]

5   b   c   d   e   f
1   2   3   4   5   6
10  20  30  40  50  60
```

As can bee seen the assignment to a spoils everything.

I have a little bit nasty solution via string matching:

```
OwnValues@pl // ToString // 
  StringCases[#, __~~"{"~~s__~~"}"~~__ :>StringSplit[s, ", "]] &//First

{"a","b","c","d","e","f"}
```

Can this be don more elegantly?

Comment: Can you put this into context?  What are you *really* trying to do?  There may be better approaches.

Comment: Well, I have tabular data (2D List), each column for some property. Each row for a set of this properties. I want to Map[Apply] various functions/evaluations for every row of this data. Not in one place but spread on different positions in a notebook. So all the functions share the same parameter list. If for some reason the layout of the data changes I would like to have on central parameter list for all the functions to be adjusted.

Comment: Why not use formal variables instead, e.g., `\[FormalA]`, `\[FormalB]` etc instead of `a`, `b` etc

Comment: @Carl Woll can you clarify your suggestion

Comment: Formal variables are protected, so you can’t give them values, and so you don’t have to worry about them having `OwnValues`

Comment: @Carl Woll, thank you, but the names of formal variables are to restrictive, further I want to be able to write (read) the names as column headers to an ASCII file.

Comment: Sorry to be off topic: @RobertNowak, Do you happen to be the Robert Nowak who wrote a Mathematica export to GDSii?  If so, I am hoping that I might be able the source to that. Kind Regards, Craig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @xzczd and @Kuba

Based on your suggestions I came up with two (three) versions, the second one with an individual parameter list which in turn is passed as a parameter:

```
a = 42;
pl := {a, b, c, d, e, f};
gl := {a, b, d, c, e, f};

Attributes[buildfunc] = {HoldAll};
buildfunc[body_] := (F \[Function] F[pl, body] /. OwnValues@pl)@Function
buildfunc[body_, 
   pl_Symbol] := (F \[Function] F[pl, body] /. OwnValues@pl)@Function
buildfunc[body_, pl_List] := (F \[Function] F[pl, body])@Function

buildfunc[c - d]
buildfunc[c - d, gl]
buildfunc[c - d, {a, b, d, c, e, f}]

buildfunc[c - d][r, s, t, u, v, w]
buildfunc[c - d, gl][r, s, t, u, v, w]
buildfunc[c - l, {a, b, f, c, e, l}][r, s, t, u, v, w]
```

gives:

```
Function[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, c - d]
Function[{a, b, d, c, e, f}, c - d]
Function[{a, b, d, c, e, f}, c - d]

t - u
-t + u
u - w
```

Seems to work pretty well.
Note the last usage with direct feed of a parameter list actually counteracts the original intention

Answer (score 4):

Would it be acceptable for you?

```
a = d = 2 (*just to test*)

myFunction // ClearAll
myFunction // Attributes = {HoldAll};
myFunction[expr_] := Function @@ Unevaluated[{{a, b, c, d, e, f}, expr}]
```

You can use your function constructor anywhere:

```
myFunction[a + b] @@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

> 3

and if data structure changes, you can redefine it with e.g.`...[{{a, c, d, e, f, b}, expr}]`

And now:

```
  myFunction[a + b] @@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

> 7

p.s. `Function @@` is there for [Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

Comment: You could also use `Hold` instead of `Unevaluated` for similar effect, I think

Comment: @b3m2a1 yes, this time it was an overreaction

Comment: I’m not sure it was an overreaction :) but perhaps a bit more complicated than you needed

Answer (score 3):

```
a = 42;
pl := {a, b, c, d, e, f};
SetAttributes[buildfunc, HoldAll]
buildfunc[body_] := (Unevaluated[#[pl, body]] /. OwnValues@pl) &@Function
(* Alternatively: *)
(*
buildfunc[body_] := Function @@ Append[Trace[pl][[2]], Unevaluated@body]
 *)

buildfunc[c + d]
pl := {a, e, f}
buildfunc[e - f]
```

---

## Update

As you've noticed, the new problem is similar to the original, so it can be solved in a similar manner:

```
a = 42;
pl := {a, b, c, d, e, f};

ClearAll[nameonly]
SetAttributes[nameonly, HoldAll]

nameonly[lst_] := HoldForm[lst] /. OwnValues@lst // Thread
(* Alternatively: *)
(*
nameonly[lst_] := Trace[lst][[2]] // Thread
 *)
TableForm[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}}, 
          TableHeadings -> {None, nameonly@pl}]
```

If you need a list of string as the output, you can:

```
(* Solution 1 *)
nameonly@pl /. HoldForm[a_] :> SymbolName@Unevaluated@a
(* Solution 2 *)
Function[a, SymbolName@Unevaluated@a, HoldAll] @@@ nameonly@pl
```

Comment: This is not a solution, because the Global a is destroyed, exactly this behavior should be avoided. The Symbol a should be kept local.

Comment: @RobertNowak `a` is not destroyed, I cleared `a` at beginning just to avoid error when this piece of code is executed repetitively. My solution will work, as long as `pl` is built before `a` owns a value. Or `a` is always defined before `pl` is defined in your actual code? If so, is modification for definiton of `pl` allowed?

Comment: Hi your "solution" works/fails exactly the same way as my simpler "solution" if I add the Clear. Imagine a large complicated notebook, I just don't want to take care If there is a Symbol a used anywhere in the code, if it is possibly used somewhere it's value should not be touched (cleared, destroyed, modified, etc.). Modification of pl is ok if it helps for a solution, for now pl is a simple list of desired formal parameters. If turning pl into some more sophisticated structure holding the parameter list helps then this would be ok.

Comment: This is a little bit confusing if you edit your solution, you should post a new answer.

Comment: @RobertNowak As far as I can tell, if an answer doesn't meet the requirement of asker, then editing the body of answer to improve or correct it rather than posting a new answer is the proper thing to do.

Comment: Ok, your actual "solution" takes only care of a, what's with b, c, d, e, f ? you would need Block[{{a, b, c, d, e, f}}, (Evaluate@pl \[Function] a + b)[r, s, t, 
  u, v, w]], Again this solution does not provide a central parameter list, if the parameter list would be needed to change to adjust for the data layout one would have to change all occurrences in all Block expressions.

Comment: @RobertNowak Again, check my edit. And, you should clarify all of these in the body of your question.

Comment: than you so far. what if I need the Symol's as a List of Strings? 
 nameonly[pl]//Map@Apply@ToStringg does not realy help me. Again a is getting spoiled.

Comment: thank you so much. Would the first question/problem have had a simpler solution if pl started as a List of String's. At least the second question/problem would have vanished :).

Comment: @RobertNowak I'm afraid the first problem won't be easier to solve, because you'll have to transform strings to symbols in some stage if you want to define function. And, I believe string will probably make things more troublesome. A solution I can think out at the moment: `a = 42;
pl := {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
ClearAll[buildfunc];
SetAttributes[buildfunc, HoldAll];
buildfunc[body_] := 
 Function[Join @@ ToExpression[pl, InputForm, HoldPattern] // Evaluate, body] /. 
   HoldPattern -> List // Quiet`

Comment: ok, managed it to get a little of a bit nicer version on the List of String's 
    buildfunc[body_] := 
         Hold[Function][ToExpression[pl, InputForm, Hold], Hold[body]] // ReleaseHold