# How to define a function inside a module through Evaluate

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I am trying to define a function inside a module as following

```
test1[a_] := Module[{sol1, g1, y},
  sol1 = Reduce[a + x^2 == y, x];
  g1[y_] := Evaluate@sol1[[1, -1]];
  Print[Definition[g1]];
  g1[33]
  ]
```

This gives the output

```
Attributes[g1$28580]={Temporary}

g1$28580[y$_]:=-Sqrt[-3+y$28580]
-Sqrt[-3 + y$28588]
```

As you can see this does not work. The `y` in the body of the function is `y$28580`, but not `y$`. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: If you use `Block` instead of `Module` does that solve the problem?

Comment: Use this: `SetDelayed @@ {g1[y_], sol1[[1, -1]]}` and read this: [Enforcing correct variable bindings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

Comment: Let me know if you disagree with marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the third line by:

```
g1[Pattern[Evaluate[y], _]] = sol1[[1, -1]];
```