# Differentiating functions of Set expressions

Tags: evaluation, hold

There are so many things in Mathematica I think I will never understand. Perhaps today there will be one fewer...

```
B'[y]/.B->Function[y,y^2]
```

Outputs `2y`. Grand.

```
expr=y^2; B'[y]/.B->Function[y,expr]
```

Outputs `0`. My usual workaround is

```
expr=y^2; B'[y]/.B->Function[Y,expr/.y->Y]
```

But then

```
expr=y^2; B'[0]/.B->Function[Y,expr/.y->Y]
```

gives me a `0 is not a valid variable` error. But then

```
B'[0]/.B->Function[y,y^2]
```

works, so now I'm just confused.

I'm sure there are other (preferred?) ways of using one of the many similar and confusing versions of `Hold`, `ReleaseHold`, `Inactive`, `Active`, `Delayed`, `Evaluate`, etc.

1) What is going on in the evaluation that allows the workaround to work. But not always. And the reason it doesn't work doesn't make other examples not work. I'm usually too impatient to care but find that it leads to such inelegant code that it has finally got the better of me.

2) What is best practice here? A contributing factor to my confusion is the myriad of `Hold` etc. options I mentioned above that I don't *really* understand. They're foreign despite me knowing 10 or so other programming languages pretty well (sure, they're not symbolic, but I find Matlab's symbolic library more intuitive at the basic level. Admittedly not done things as advanced as with Mathematica, but this is pretty basic).

Comment: try `B'[y] /. B -> Function[y, Evaluate@expr]`?

Comment: @kglr, but `Module[{expr},expr=y^2;B'[y] /. B -> Function[y, Evaluate@expr]]` doesn't work, so this doesn't really solve my problem

Comment: `Module` is actually causing another issue. Anyway, the following will work: `Module[{expr}, expr = y^2; B'[y] /. B -> Function @@ {y, expr}]`

Comment: @xzczd, thanks for the workaround! Do you see, especially in light of this workaround that seems almost identical to the original, why all of this is so confusing?

Comment: Well, the underlying rule isn't complicated actually, in short, `Function` only sees **explicit** variables, but I haven't yet find a carnonical post that explains this in a detailed enough way, so I've just started a meta-post regarding to the 1st question: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2414/1871 As to the 2nd question about `Module`, you may want to read this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/1871