# Assigning values to variables inside Module using user defined function

Tags: function-construction, scoping

Say I'm defining a function 
with some local variables, for which I'm using `Module`. Now, I want to assign some value (or perhaps a list of values or a list of list, etc.) to some of those variables. Can I use a previously user defined function (which itself might have been built using `Module`) to do so? Here is an example (probably not the best) of what I am asking for, hope it's clear enough:

```
f[y_]:= y^2

SinFunction[x_]:=Module[{g},    
 g = f[x];    
 Sin[g]    
]

SinFunction[0.5]
```

> 0.247404

I mean it does work, in this case, but is it a good practice? What could possibly have gone wrong?

Comment: I see no problem with what you're doing here, regardless of whether or not `f` uses `Module`. The idea behind scoping constructs is that you can nest them, so this is perfectly allowable.

Comment: You just need to watch out when you nest them explicitly: [enforcing-correct-variable-bindings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

Comment: Thank you @SjoerdSmit ! I thought that the idea was correct. The reason I asked is that I'm trying to find out where the error comes from in my code and I thought I might have been due to the way I constructed my functions. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. I'll look into it.