# Using Solve[] in Module

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, scoping

```
Clear[x, y];
function2[eqn3_, eqn4_] := 
 Module[{x, y, sol}, sol = Solve[{eqn3, eqn4}, {x, y}]; {x, y} /. sol]
function2[y == 3 x, y == x^2 - 4]
```

I want it to solve for x and y but this wouldnt work. I am not quite sure about how to use Solve in a Module

Answer (score 2):

It is best to pass the variables to the function

```
function2[eqn3_, eqn4_, x_, y_] := Module[{sol},
  sol = Solve[{eqn3, eqn4}, {x, y}];
  {x, y} /. sol
  ]
function2[y == 3 x, y == x^2 - 4, x, y]
```

Gives

```
{{-1, -3}, {4, 12}}
```

Otherwise, different context.

When you did this

```
function2[eqn3_, eqn4_] := Module[{x, y, sol},
  sol = Solve[{eqn3, eqn4}, {x, y}];
  {x, y} /. sol
  ]
function2[y == 3 x, y == x^2 - 4]
```

Then the `x,y` in the equations are global context, but then you defined local `x,y` inside the module, which are different context (even though they look the same on the screen), they are different symbols under the cover.

Comment: You were just a few seconds faster ;-). I propose something like `systemSolver[system_List, vars_List] := Module[{sol},
  sol = Solve[system, vars];
  vars /. sol
  ]` its more flexible like the OP version, but her is only duplicates `Solve` ;-)

Comment: This is a common problem in  more general settings. Is there a general post on this issue? I think there are two problems: 1) having to input the variables and 2) having to output the solution if it contains variables.  For outputting the solution one may use pure functions. [See here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/12558)