# Solve variable inside Module

Tags: equation-solving, scoping

Suppose I have a `Module` in which I use `Solve[]`. If I make the solve variable local,
I get this:

```
f[a_] := Module[{soln, x},
   soln = Solve[2 x == a, {x}];
   Return[soln]
   ];
f[5]
(*{{x$117834 -> 5/2}}*)
```

If instead I leave the solve variable global, I get this cleaner result:

```
g[a_] := Module[{soln},
   soln = Solve[2 x == a, {x}];
   Return[soln]
   ];
g[5]
(*{{x -> 5/2}}*)
```

But if globally x has a value, x=7, this fails:

```
(*7 is not a valid variable*)
```

Why does the local variable `x` in the first example become `x$117834`? What is the
best way to use variables like `x` in this circumstance?

Comment: This has been asked before many times. It is best to pass the `x` along with `a` to the module to avoid all these issues. That would be the safest method. See [using-solve-in-module](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/217103/using-solve-in-module/217105#217105) as an example.

Comment: @Nasser: Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) The method used by `Module` to emulate lexical scoping involves renaming in the way you see. Usually this is invisible because usually variables local to a `Module` are not explicitly returned in the result.

(2) If your variable has been assigned a value then even if you manage to get past renaming the result will still not be what you might have expected.

One way to bypass the renaming is to use `Block` instead of `Module` (`Block` emulates dynamic scoping by temporarily "forgetting" any values attached to the symbol).

```
f[a_] := Block[{soln, x},
  soln = Solve[2 x == a, {x}];
  soln]
f[5]

(* Out[68]= {{x -> 5/2}} *)
```

Well and good. Now assign a value to `x`.

```
x = 7;
f[5]

(* Out[70]= {{7 -> 5/2}} *)
```

The upshot is that it will be difficult to do this with a variable that has been assigned a value. No surprises there; this would be the case in any language.