# Set keeps RHS unevaluated when RHS is a Module variable

Tags: scoping, assignment

Consider the simple code

```
r`outsideFormula = x;
Module[{f, g, insideFormula = 2 x}, 
 f[x_] = r`outsideFormula;
 Print@f@1(*works*);
 g[x_] = insideFormula;
 Print@g@1(*won't work*)
 ]
(*
1
2x
*)
```

When the formula defined outside the `Module` is used in the RHS of `Set`, it works upon successive evaluations as expected. However if a `Module` variable is used (`insideFormula`), it apparently remains unevaluated.

*Why is this?*

Comment: `Print@DownValues@f` to see what is going on and read [avoiding-renamings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20766/enforcing-correct-variable-bindings-and-avoiding-renamings-for-conflicting-varia) to learn why

Comment: @Nasser it is `2x` but for `f[ x$_]`, notice `$`.

Comment: @Nasser Whether or not `x` is localized the Module in the second definition will rename `x_` to `x$_` making it different than `x` from the RHS. That is explained in the topic linked in my first comment.

Comment: @Nasser didn't nest any modules here...Kuba's "renaming of x to x$" explanation seems correct

Comment: @Kuba the linked explanation is a bit difficult for me to understand (and long). If time permits, would you mind adding an explanation in simpler words? Originally, the problem was that some complicatedly named var `Global'complicatedName` had a formula with symbols. I opened a `Module` to evaluate it for different values of those symbols (instead of using /.symbol->value) and some other manipulations ...while doing all this, instead of rewriting everytime complicatedName, I thought I'll alias it in `Module` vars and that's when I found the difference. btw, your `x$` explanation works

Comment: I doubt I can do a better job than what's in the first paragraph of the accepted answer there. I am encouraging you to try to go through it.