Problem defining Function inside Module to verify ODE solution
I modified the question. It turns out this problem has nothing to do with using a package. New style or standard style./
Same problem shows in a normal module in notebook.
This is the most bizzar thing I have ever seen so far in Mathematica.
I made a module, which I pass it the ode, and the solution. Inside the module it makes Function to use to verify the ode again. Normal standard thing.
If I assign the passed in solution to a local module variable first, then the verification fails.  The question is why?
Here is MWE
ClearAll[y,x];

ode=y'[x]-2*y[x]==2*Sqrt[y[x]]
ic=y[0]==1
sol=y[x]==(-1+2 Exp[x])^2

verify[ode_,y_[x_],x_,sol_,ic_]:=Module[{f,solY},
solY=sol[[2]];
f=y->Function[{x},Evaluate[solY]];
FullSimplify[{ode,ic}/.f]
];

Now make the call
verify[ode, y[x], x, sol, ic]

It gives

Now I change the module to this. Notice, I do not assign the solution to a local variable now. But use it directly.
verify[ode_, y_[x_], x_, sol_, ic_] := Module[{f},
   f = y -> Function[{x}, Evaluate[sol[[2]]]];
   FullSimplify[{ode, ic} /. f]
   ];

And using same call
  verify[ode, y[x], x, sol, ic]

It now gives

Why? In my code, I must assign the solution to local variable first. I do not see why this will break things.
Is there a workaround while still being able to assign the input solution to local module variable before using it in Function ?
V 14

Out of curiosity, why not write your packages using the documented and supported package format?  This "new" package format seems like nothing but trouble.

Agreed. I get the impression that the new style package format is not going to be documented any time soon, making it difficult to understand how exactly you're supposed to use it. I exclusively use the documented format nowadays.

@jason  I am only trying the new style since it allowed me more easily to make subpackages and use fully qualified name for each. I agree, this is not working at all with these kind of nasty bugs. I will stop using the new style now and change all my code to the current format. Will keep this question open in case someone else has same problem.

@JasonB.  Same problem shows up in the current standard package style also. This makes no sense at all.  Should I make new question or add to this question?  It might be more clear to make new question. What do you think?

It turns out this has nothing to do with package at all. Same problem happens in notebook using normal module. Will adjust this question now to say so.

A better duplicate candidate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/1871 As mentioned in the post, one possible fix is: verify[ode_, y_[x_], x_, sol_, ic_] := Module[{f, solY}, solY = sol[[2]];   f = y -> Function @@ {{x}, solY};   FullSimplify[{ode, ic} /. f]]

@xzczd great find !   Using Function @@ {{x}, solY}; did it. I would never have figured this myself. Mathematica can really be confusing sometimes :)
